# Forcing fputcsv to Use Enclosure For *all* Fields

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

When I use [fputcsv](http://php.net/fputcsv) to write out a line to an open file handle, PHP will add an enclosing character to any column that it believes needs it, but will leave other columns without the enclosures.

For example, you might end up with a line like this

```
11,"Bob ",Jenkins,"200 main st. USA ",etc
```

Short of appending a bogus space to the end of every field, is there any way to force fputcsv to always enclose columns with the enclosure (defaults to a ") character?

Comment: Just curious, as my guess is that you're question was in:re to `Magento/Varien_Io_File::streamWriteCsv()` (which ultimately just uses `fputcsv`), did you ever find a good solution for this? Possibly using `Varien_File_Csv`?

Comment: @pspahn Never did, (and this was four+ years ago, but I don't think it was specifically Magento related)

Comment: Take a look at this custom fputcsv implementation that should fit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682050/592868

Answer (score 35, accepted):

No, fputcsv() only encloses the field under the following conditions

```
/* enclose a field that contains a delimiter, an enclosure character, or a newline */
if (FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(delimiter) ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(enclosure) ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(escape_char) ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK('\n') ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK('\r') ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK('\t') ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(' ')
)
```

There is no "always enclose" option.

Comment: sad, because fgetcsv fails with Österreich without double quotes!

Comment: VolkerK is, of course quite right. fputcsv cannot help you with this problem (I have the same issue). Let me help you get a jump start on the next search you will be doing: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv)

Comment: where did you find this? What is your source?

Comment: @relipse It's from the php source code, in [/ext/standard/file.c php_fputcsv](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/file.c#L1873)

Answer (score 22):

Building on [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3536236/martin)'s answer, if you want to avoid inserting any characters that don't stem from the source array (`Chr(127)`, `Chr(0)`, etc), you can replace the fputcsv() line with the following instead:

```
fputs($fp, implode(",", array_map("encodeFunc", $row))."\r\n");
```

Granted, fputs() is slower than fputcsv(), but it's a cleaner output. The complete code is thus:

```
/***
 * @param $value array
 * @return string array values enclosed in quotes every time.
 */
function encodeFunc($value) {
    ///remove any ESCAPED double quotes within string.
    $value = str_replace('\\"','"',$value);
    //then force escape these same double quotes And Any UNESCAPED Ones.
    $value = str_replace('"','\"',$value);
    //force wrap value in quotes and return
    return '"'.$value.'"';
}

$fp = fopen("filename.csv", 'w');
foreach($table as $row){
    fputs($fp, implode(",", array_map("encodeFunc", $row))."\r\n");
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I did actually find after posting this answer that with `fputcsv` that the function really is pretty lame and using standard *write-to-file* functions as you've also done sorted my code out and sidestepped all issues with CSV consistency across platforms and programs.

Comment: Thank you for the good example.  I needed to always enclose all values in quotes.  And, I needed to force the line endings to CR+LF instead of just LF.  This example solves both problems.

Answer (score 21):

Not happy with this solution but it is what I did and worked. The idea is to set an empty char as enclosure character on fputcsv and add some quotes on every element of your array.

```
function encodeFunc($value) {
    return "\"$value\"";
}

fputcsv($handler, array_map(encodeFunc, $array), ',', chr(0));
```

Comment: Including chr(0) in the file causes issues in some import scripts if the file is UTF-8

Comment: the csv contain ^@ if you are using chr(0)

Comment: You can get rid of the nulls (chr(0)) in the resulting file by filtering them after you are done outputing your csv: `file_put_contents($file, str_replace(chr(0), '', file_get_contents($file)));`. Also your `encodeFunc` will need to escape double quotes as well if your values have them. See my revision [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/223ea7353626bc6a6a9e#file-csvenclosed-php). Other than that it seems to work, just keep in mind it's a hack.

Comment: don't forget to escape quotes in data value itself. as said in the RFC 4180 standard, when the `enclosure` is a `"`, the escape character is the `"` as well (escape character = enclosure). So the `$value` in the loop should be manipulated like this: `$value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);`

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of scrafffing around and some somewhat tedious character checking, I have a version of the above referenced codes by [Diego](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21321219/3536236) and [Mahn](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/223ea7353626bc6a6a9e#file-csvenclosed-php) that will correctly strip out encasings and replace with double quotes on all fields in `fputcsv`. and then output the file to the browser to download.

I also had a secondary issue of not being able to be sure that double quotes were always / never escaped.

Specifically for when outputting directly to browser using the php://input stream as referenced by Diego. `Chr(127)` is a space character so the CSV file has a few more spaces than otherwise but I believe this sidesteps the issue of `chr(0)` NULL characters in UTF-8.

```
/***
 * @param $value array
 * @return string array values enclosed in quotes every time.
 */
function encodeFunc($value) {
    ///remove any ESCAPED double quotes within string.
    $value = str_replace('\\"','"',$value);
    //then force escape these same double quotes And Any UNESCAPED Ones.
    $value = str_replace('"','\"',$value);
    //force wrap value in quotes and return
    return '"'.$value.'"';
}


$result = $array_Set_Of_DataBase_Results;
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export-'.date("d-m-Y").'.csv"');
    foreach($result as $row) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_map("encodeFunc", $row), ',', chr(127));
    }
    unset($result,$row);
    die;
}
```

I hope this is useful for some one.

Answer (score 0):

A function to auto create and download in browser a csv while forcing to enclose all or only specified columns

It uses a string, that is quite unlikely to existing in the dataset, which contains at least one space and this forces the the enclosure.

After fputsv does it's job you retrieve the file and replace the forcing string with empty character.
This cannot work in large streams of data unless you modify it but for most applications it's should be sufficient

Just input the columns you want to force enlcose or ['*'] to enclose everything and in case for some strange reason the forcing string is already included in your data you can pass a different non existing string to force enclose

```
function csvDownload(
        array   $array,
        string  $filename = "export.csv",
        ?string $separator = ",",
        ?string $enclosure = '"',
        ?string $escape = "\\",
        ?array  $forceEnclose = [],
        string  $forceString = '{ || force enclosing || }'
    ): void
    {
        $tempFile = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
        foreach ($array as $line) {
            fputcsv(
                $tempFile,
                array_map(
                    function ($value, $key) use ($forceEnclose, $forceString) {
                        if (
                            in_array($key, $forceEnclose, true) ||
                            in_array('*', $forceEnclose, true)
                        ) {
                            $value .= $forceString;
                        }
                        return $value;
                    },
                    $line,
                    array_keys($line)
                ),
                $separator,
                $enclosure,
                $escape
            );
        }
        rewind($tempFile);
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');
        echo str_replace(
            $forceString,
            '',
            stream_get_contents($tempFile)
        );
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

A "quick and dirty" solution is to add ' ' at the end of all of your fields, if it's acceptable for you:

```
fputcsv($handle, array_map(fn($v) => $v.' ', $fields));
```

PS: why it's working? see [Volkerk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833/volkerk) answer ;)

Comment: that's not a solution, it changes the content of each field.

Comment: that's why it's called a "quick and dirty" solution