# php fputcsv and enclosing fields

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I was just about to ask the same questions as the question aksed here.... [Forcing fputcsv to Use Enclosure For *all* Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489553/forcing-fputcsv-to-use-enclosure-for-all-fields)

The question was

> When I use fputcsv to write out a line
>   to an open file handle, PHP will add
>   an enclosing character to any column
>   that it believes needs it, but will
>   leave other  columns without the
>   enclosures.
>
> For example, you might end up with a
>   line like this
>
> 11,"Bob ",Jenkins,"200 main st. USA
>   ",etc
>
> Short of appending a bogus space to
>   the end of every field, is there any
>   way to force fputcsv to always enclose
>   columns with the enclosure (defaults
>   to a ") character?

The answer was:

> No, fputcsv() only encloses the field
>   under the following conditions

```
/* enclose a field that contains a delimiter, an enclosure character, or a newline */
if (FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(delimiter) ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(enclosure) ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(escape_char) ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK('\n') ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK('\r') ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK('\t') ||
  FPUTCSV_FLD_CHK(' ')
)
```

> There is no "always enclose" option.

I need to create a CSV file will every field enclosed... What would be the best solution?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Would changing the php sources be an option? I.e. is adding some "enclose always" flag to the function parameters feasible in your case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Roll your own function - its not hard:

```
 function dumbcsv($file_handle, $data_array, $enclosure, $field_sep, $record_sep)
 {
     dumbescape(false, $enclosure);
     $data_array=array_map('dumbescape',$data_array);
     return fputs($file_handle, 
         $enclosure 
         . implode($enclosure . $field_sep . $enclosure, $data_array)
         . $enclosure . $record_sep);
 }
 function dumbescape($in, $enclosure=false)
 {
    static $enc;
    if ($enclosure===false) {
        return str_replace($enc, '\\' . $enc, $in);
    }
    $enc=$enclosure;
 }
```

(above is using unix style escaping)

C.

Comment: $file_handle, $data_array, $enclosure, $field_sep, $record_sep - can you example what are values need to be passed ... please ... thank you in advance

Comment: $file_handle what value need to pass for this variable @symcbean

Comment: return fputs($file_handle, 
         $enclosure 
         . implode($enclosure . $field_sep . $enclosure, $data_array)
         . $enclosure . $record_sep);
 I am getting error in this line Message:  Array to string conversion

Answer (score 1):

A workaround: Supposing you have your data in a 2-dimensional array, you can append a string that will force quoting and you are sure is not contained in your data ("#@ @#" here) and then remove it:

```
    $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
    foreach ($data as $line => $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            $row[$key] = $value."#@ @#";
        }           
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }

    fclose($fp);
    $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
    $contents = str_replace("#@ @#", "", $contents);
    file_put_contents($filename, $contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem, and I have solved it as follows.
I have inserted single quotes to each array value.
This way when you open the csv file with excel, the scientific notation E + 15 will no longer be displayed.

Here I share you as I did.

This worked for me, I hope you do too.
Regards

```
        // this function add a single quote for each member of array
         function insertquote($value) {
            return "'$value'";
        }

        # here i send each value of array 
        # to a insertquote function, and returns an array with new values, 
        # with the single quote.

        foreach ($list as $ferow) {
            fputcsv($fp, array_map(insertquote, $ferrow), ';');
        }
```