# fputcsv force all values to have quotes or non at all

Tags: php

i'm using `fputcsv` and its only putting input text type values into quotes. Is there a way to override this and either force all to have quotes or remove them all together? I tried `fputcsv($fp, $data, ',', '"');` but that didn't work

```
$data = array_values($_POST);
if( $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a+') ){
    fputcsv($fp, $data);
}
fclose($fp);
```

**csv data example: "user","city",yes,no,10001**

Comment: Already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514597/php-fputcsv-and-enclosing-fields

Answer (score 1):

You can force each entry to be quoted by appending a space, then remove that space using a stream filter before it gets written to the .csv

```
/* Function to append a space to each element in the array */
function addSpace(&$var, $key){ $var .= ' '; }

/* Filter class to remove the space previously appended */
class space_filter extends php_user_filter {
  function filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
  {
    while ($bucket = stream_bucket_make_writeable($in)) {
      $bucket->data = str_replace(' "', '"', $bucket->data);
      $consumed += $bucket->datalen;
      stream_bucket_append($out, $bucket);
    }
    return PSFS_PASS_ON;
  }
}

/* Register filter */
stream_filter_register("filterspace", "space_filter");

$arr = array("user","city","yes","no","10001"); // your array

/* use addSpace on each element in the array */
array_walk($arr, "addSpace");

if( $fp = fopen('data.csv', 'a+') ){
    stream_filter_append($fp, "filterspace"); // Remove space 
    fputcsv($fp, $arr);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Results in: "user","city","yes","no","10001"

I just wrote this out of curiosity, you probably shouldn't use this for anything important.