# Escaping for CSV

Tags: php, regex

I need to store a string in a MySQL database. The values will later be used in a CSV. How do I escape the string so that it is CSV-safe? I assume I need to escape the following: comma, single quote, double quote.

PHP's `addslashes` function does:

> single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).

So that won't work. Suggestions? I'd rather not try to create some sort of regex solution.

Also, I need to be able to unescape.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write, and [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read.

Comment: do those support encoding of newlines and double quotes?

Comment: I dont want to write it to a file :(

Comment: @NDM - you don't have to. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13474770/702420

Comment: IF you use `;` as a delimiter with `fputcsv()` and you have a semicolon and quotation marks in your string, it breaks. Probably related to https://github.com/ajgarlag/AjglCsvRfc

Answer (score 25):

`fputcsv()` is not always necessary especially if you don't need to write any file but you want to return the CSV as an HTTP response.
All you need to do is to double quote each value and to escape double quote characters repeating a double quote each time you find one.

Here a few examples:

```
hello -> "hello"
this is my "quote" -> "this is my ""quote"""
catch 'em all -> "catch 'em all"
```

As you can see the single quote character doesn't need any escaping.

Follows a full working example:

```php
<?php

$arrayToCsvLine = function(array $values) {
    $line = '';

    $values = array_map(function ($v) {
        return '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $v) . '"';
    }, $values);

    $line .= implode(',', $values);

    return $line;
};

$csv = [];
$csv[] = $arrayToCsvLine(["hello", 'this is my "quote"', "catch 'em all"]);
$csv[] = $arrayToCsvLine(["hello", 'this is my "quote"', "catch 'em all"]);
$csv[] = $arrayToCsvLine(["hello", 'this is my "quote"', "catch 'em all"]);

$csv = implode("\r\n", $csv);
```

If you get an error is just because you're using an old version of PHP. Fix it by declaring the arrays with their old syntax and replacing the lambda function with a classic one.

Comment: You can still use `fputcsv` if you make your file handle like this: `$fh = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );` and add the necessary headers. [source](http://ran.ge/2009/10/27/howto-create-stream-csv-php/)

Comment: Yep, writing to a stream is for sure another option.

Comment: This was the first answer of many that actually provided a raw solution without pointing out the function "fgetscsv" and "fputcsv". Thank you!

Comment: This breaks when there are newlines in the string.

Comment: RFC 4180 says you should use CRLF as line break. Translated to PHP, that is `\r\n`. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: Was looking into escaping csv output during iteration. For this example, to reduce the function calls, [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) also accepts an array of strings, allowing you to move the double quoted value wrapping into `implode` Like so https://3v4l.org/YWTI4 `$line .= '"' . implode('","', str_replace('"', '""', $values)) . '"' . "\r\n";`

Comment: It should be noted that PHP did not support anonymous functions until version 5.3. So, if you are using an earlier version you will need to create a function in the traditional way.

Answer (score 24):

For those of you trying to sanitise data using PHP and output as a CSV this can be done using PHP's fputcsv() function without having to write to a file as such:

```
<?php
// An example PHP array holding data to be put into CSV format
$data = [];
$data[] = ['row1_val1', 'row1_val2', 'row1_val3'];
$data[] = ['row2_val1', 'row2_val2', 'row2_val3'];

// Write to memory (unless buffer exceeds 2mb when it will write to /tmp)
$fp = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
foreach ($data as $fields) {
    // Add row to CSV buffer
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
rewind($fp); // Set the pointer back to the start
$csv_contents = stream_get_contents($fp); // Fetch the contents of our CSV
fclose($fp); // Close our pointer and free up memory and /tmp space

// Handle/Output your final sanitised CSV contents
echo $csv_contents;
```

Comment: This worked great! I sent csv headers and output using this to create dynamic csv files for Drupal Feeds importer.

Answer (score 18):

Don't store the data CSV escaped in the database. Escape it **when you export to CSV using [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv)**. If you're storing it CSV escaped you're essentially storing garbage for all purposes other than CSV exporting.

Comment: I agree.  I would rather take a small performance hit (of escaping the data several times going out) for the sake of having correctly stored data.