# php including a htmlcode snippet as a single field in a CSV using fputcsv

Tags: php, excel, csv, fputcsv

I am generating a csv from an array of arrays using fputcsv() . One of the field contians a html code snippet and it is causing problems when I open it in Excel.

When opened in excel , it breaks across multiple cells .

Please note that in the fputcsv I have used `,` as the delimiter and `"` as the enclosing element.

Still I could see that the html string was being broken across multiple cells , and this was occuring because of commas inside the htmlcontent .

So , how can I exactly escape the inlying commas ?

For the time being , I did replace the commas with whitespace . But , still I am seeing that a long htmlcode (nearabout 53823 characters) breaks across multiple cells when opened in MS Excel . Is there any upper limit to the number of characters that a single cell in Excel can contain?

Please note that when I open my csv in Notepad++ , it shows that the CSV is well formed without any breaks in between. However , my client uses MS Excel , and it's kind of hard convincing him that the CSV is actually well formed . Please help.

Here's the code that I have been using :

```
//escape the newline characters
$template = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $template);
$cache = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $cache);

$fh = fopen('abc.csv', 'a');
fputcsv($fh,array($template,$cache),',','"');
```

the `$template` and `$cache` are having html code snippet as field values.

Also , what I noticed is that if I don't escape the `,` , the string breaks across multiple cells . For this I have tried to `str_replace(",","\,",$string)` but to no use.

Update : The issue is in cases where both quotes and comma occur inside a string . 
e.g consider a string `I have "big" quesiton, that I want to know.`

`"I have "big" quesiton"` comes in one cell and `"that I want to know."` comes in another cell instead of the entire string occuring in one column.

Comment: can you show your code ??

Comment: Does your HTML contain double-quotes `(")`? If so you should escape them using backslash `(\)`

Comment: Did a quick search, and it seems fputcsv actually does the escaping for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325613/escaping-for-csv
So you need to post code to get any further with this issue.

Comment: Tested a short HTML snippet with `fputcsv` under PHP 5.3.10 and opened with Excel 2003, it works fine. Try to chop down your suspiciously long HTML code to a much shorter one to test.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use a free PHP excel exporter class by Eli Dickinson, I was born again when starting using it, no problems now whatsoever when generating and opening the files on client`s side. Here is the link: 
http://github.com/elidickinson/php-export-data