# How to keep backslash or change it to NULL in CSV file to generate SQL file in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

\I am generating SQL file from CSV file, but have some string files with slashes and the value is like:

```
 "aaa", "\", 111, 222, "bbb", "\", 333
```

The value between "\" will be generated as one string

```
'\", 111, 222, "bbb", "\', 333
```

But I hope to keep "\" as it should to be, or change it to NULL, like:

```
'NULL', 111, 222, 'bbb', 'NULL', 333
```

My code is like this:

```
while (($lineArr = fgetcsv($infile))!=FALSE){
foreach($lineArr as $line){
...
if ($line == '\\"')
$line = 'NULL';
...
}
}
```

This dose not work. I think `$line =='\\"'` is not correct, but I do not know how to process the whole part between "\".

solution:
I first change the array to string to process the '"\"', then change it back to array for further process.

```
while (($lineArr = fgetcsv($infile))!=FALSE){
$string = implode(",", $lineArr);
    if (strpos($string,',\",')){
        $sKeepSlash = str_replace(',\",', ",NULL,", $string);
        $pLineArr = explode(',', $sKeepSlash);
    }
    foreach($lineArr as $line){
    ...
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: Add another \ before it so there are 2 backslashes, like "\\"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping for CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325613/escaping-for-csv)

Answer (score 1):

> Use `fputcsv()`
>   to write, and `fgetcsv()`
>   to read.

Found here: [Escaping for CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325613/escaping-for-csv)

Comment: My csv file is downloaded from other system, so this means I need first using fputcsv() to create a new csv file and then using fgetcsv() to process it?

Comment: You should be able to process it the first run if they provide a valid feed. Try lkooking around for `csv escape`

Answer (score 0):

Find the position for the slashes first. For example, you can user [array_keys](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php).

this will return the positions of the markers. You can then use that to combine

```
$marker_positions = array_keys($array, "marker");
for ($position = $marker_positions[0]+1; $position < $marker_positions[0]; $position++) {
    $single_string .= $array[$position];
}
```