# Exporting MySQL tables to csv locally

Tags: php, sql, csv, export

I want to export two tables from my mysql server to a csv file on the webserver.

Both the mysql and webserver are running on the same machine, and will NOT be web-facing. It's merely a small webapp to automate a task I perform on a regular basis, and so security is not an issue.

The way I tried, which would be absolutely ideal, but did not work was:

```
$exportArticle = 'SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE "article_line.csv"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
ENCLOSED BY "\""
ESCAPED BY "\\"
LINES TERMINATED BY "\\n\\r"
FROM article_line';
```

and then calling it in my script with:

```
mysql_query($exportArticle);
```

But unfortunately this doesn't write anything (it doesn't error out, either, though.)

If someone could help me with this, that would be great! Thanks

EDIT: Just to clarify, I have spent the last 2 and a half hours browsing both google and stackoverflow looking for solutions for this, and have tried so many different ways it's not funny. It's just ending up a muddle in my head that I can't understand, so apologies if anyone believes the answer is already here - it hasn't worked for me so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Comment: You need to make sure that you have write access to the location where are you trying to write the file.

Comment: I made the same once....and just like you i thought that doesnt work, but it works....try to copy and paste the query in your mysql client or in phpmyadmin and run it, just to see if trigger some error

Comment: @RelevantUsername - I've already checked that link, and it's either not working for me, or I'm just too novice to get it to work.

Comment: @Sumoanand - It definitely has write access, as other commands in the same script have successfully written to the same location.

Comment: @BrodieMessenger You might be interested to know that if the Database and PHP are on the same server, you could do something like a direct CSV export from a single mysql command, more informations here : http://ariejan.net/2008/11/27/export-csv-directly-from-mysql/

Comment: @RobertRozas- Thanks for the suggestion Robert; Unfortunately I've already done this, and running it directly on the database works fine, that's why I'm stumped as to why it doesn't when executing via my php script.

Comment: @RelevantUsername- Thanks for the suggestion. I have actually already seen this article, and this is pretty much exactly what my script is already doing(just not successfully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to

```
mysql_query($exportArticle) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will give you an idea if there is any error when executing the query. If you don't do error handling on `mysql_query` it will continue to the next statement even if there is an error.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.

I didn't even consider that - my mind isn't operating well on a Friday night after hours of coding.

I worked it out thanks to your solution - the formatting of my FROM was missing backticks.

Answer (score 0):

you can just download [MysqlWorkbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) , then do

```
SELECT * FROM article_line
```

you will se then abutton like this [image]

just click on it and you will have the csv export option in there

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - this is how I was doing it originally, except through SQLYog. The reason I wanted to script it was because A. it saves a step, but B. to make it user-friendly so that non-technical persons can use it.

Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you managed to do it but I think that this command has a problem with php.
Maybe the access to that file is denied. If you want to create the resulting file on some client host other than the server host, you cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

You can use instead something like this.

```
function sqlQueryToCSV($filename, $query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
        $headers = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
                $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
        }
        $fp = fopen(mysql_real_escape_string(getcwd().'\\'.$filename), 'w');
        if ($fp) {  fputcsv($fp, $headers);  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
         $arrayValues = array();
         foreach ($headers as $header)
         {
             $arrayValues[] = $row[$header];
         }
         fputcsv($fp, $arrayValues);  }
        }
        fclose($fp); }
```

Source: http://forums.exchangecore.com/topic/907-function-to-convert-mysql-query-to-csv-file-with-php/