# Saving PHP Table as CSV

Tags: php, html, mysql, export-to-csv

I have been looking everywhere for a way to do this.

There are a lot of people that have asked the questions but when I try myself I can't seem to get it to work.

Often I get the format correct but it inputs the information into a new page instead of saving it.

I did manage to get one to work for Google Chrome but when I ran it in internet explorer it didn't work.

I have a table being created from a MYSQL query and i would like the table to be able to be saved as a CSV.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: post the code you tried, and explain how it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Comment: Please don't spend half the question beating around the bush. Explain exactly what you're trying to do, *how* you're trying to do it and what exactly goes wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [`INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html) clause:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, ...
  INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
   FROM tablename 
  WHERE ...
```

Comment: Some caveats: This file is created on the MySQL server, not on the client, and secondly, on some systems with a more robust `/tmp` filesystem the file might end up in `/tmp/systemd-private-XXXXX` where `XXXXX` is some random letters.