# Export/Import some data from database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I want to export and import from my database, including a WHERE clause, to export some data and not all (For example: Exporting all data tables where numberID = 25). So, It's possible to do that? And, If it is possible, how I could import those data? Removing first previous data?

I was trying to export them from my database, but it doesn't work: What I did wrong? I'm working with XAMPP. Thanks for all!

```
<?php

//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='myDatabase';
$mysqlUserName ='myUser';
$mysqlPassword ='myPass';
$mysqlExportPath =$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/backup.sql';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';

$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' > ' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command);

?>
```

Comment: So, where is the SQL statement you're trying to get to work?

Comment: open up `phpmyadmin` make a `SELECT` for whatever rows you want and tick "check all" on the bottom there is a "export" click and there you go.

Comment: With 'mysqldump' is no sufficient? where must be my sql statement? thanks ChrisW

Comment: Thanks Kyslik, but i want to use php because the users can't access to phpmyadmin

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you had so little understanding of what you want to do.  You really need to do some googling on MySQL / PHP - and **please make sure** you use PDO functions, not `mysql_*` ones (try a tutorial such as http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: Thanks ChrisW, but all my project have procedural programming...

Comment: @JuanAntonio PDO can be used in a procedural manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to use mysqldump (it is more like an administration/backup tool and to my knowledge can only export whole tables), but try a SELECT statement with a WHERE clause for reading your data. Export it in the file format you would like to, e.g. XML oder CSV. For importing the data again, use a DELETE statement for deleting the present data (also applying the WHERE clause) and use INSERT statements for each record in the input file.

Comment: Thanks Matthias Wuttke, I'll try it!

Comment: Can you tell me an example to how export my query in .xml or .sql? thanks!

Comment: @JuanAntonio - why do you think you need to export your query?

Comment: I understood that i need to export my result data from my query and to import, read the archive. Isn't it?

Comment: No, not at all. See my answer.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php - use this code to export the database table content to a CSV file; then there is plenty of code on how to import the CSV file again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table such as

```
ID | COL1 | COL 2
-----------------
 1 |  A1  |  A2
 2 |  B1  |  B2
```

Use the following PHP code to display the whole table

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM table') as $row) {
    echo $row['field1'].' '.$row['field2']; //etc...
}
?>
```

This code is take *ad verbatim* from the link I provided earlier (I am being particularly kind - the vast majority of people wouldn't give you a link and then when you clearly hadn't read it still give you the code...).

The query can be extended to something such as `'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID=2'`.  Of course, you can still put any kind of HTML in the PHP `forloop` to display the data anyway you want

Answer (score 0):

As already stated I wouldn't use `mysqldump` but a `select` query.
Having said that you can add a `--where` statement to `mysqldump` as described on the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)

`mysqldump -t -u [username] -p[password] [database] [table] --where=[statement]`

Also, you are trying to save the .sql file in your document root, you need to check the permissions. However having the document root writable by the Apache user is not a good idea.