# How can I put data from an array to a .csv?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, export

I have 2 csv documents. I have a code that counts how many rows don't exist in the old csv that are in the new.

My task is to create a new csv and put those rows in it.

What command or function can I use to do it with PHP?

Comment: [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) ?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
  $rows = array(
     array('a', 'b', 'c'),
     array('b', 'c', 'a')
  );

  $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
  foreach ($rows as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
  }

  fclose($fp);
```

Comment: It worked with something like this, thanks for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

user3215319 got it close...

```
$myarray = array(
    array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four'),
    array('red', 'yellow', 'green', 'brown'),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4),
);

$mycsv = fopen('myfile.csv', 'w');
foreach ($myarray as $row) {
    fputcsv($mycsv, $row);
}

fclose($mycsv);
```