# converting Query Results to CSV

Tags: asp.net, csv

Hi Experts i have question . My users will have a asp.net web page . User will simply execute a store procedure using button click . Store procedure will produce some results i want to export those results into CSV format 
Regards

Comment: What's the question? You might consider discussing the web page server side technology, where you want the results delivered (file on the server, to the client as a download, something else...) and anything else pertinent.

Comment: Well question is "I Export SQL Query results into CSV format " My database is SQL server 2005 .

Comment: So you want people to be able go onto a website, run a query and export the results as a CSV?  If so, you may want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php as you will want to do it via the web page side of things rather than the database side of things

Comment: Well thanks I already know database side using SQLCMD . But from web page asp.net page user will just click on button which executes store procedure that produce a results i want those results exported into CSV thats thanks for your support. I prefer web page side of things

Comment: Is this not, therefore, an ASP.net question rather than a SQL question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the results are strongly typed (or you can map it to a list of entities) you can use LINQ To CSV library:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25133/LINQ-to-CSV-library