# Getting specific value from multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am having a multidimensional array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 12
            [userid] => 001


        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 13                
            [userid] => 002

        )

)
```

I want to display the userid values from both like "001, 002" as a string with comma separated.

Comment: http://php.net/foreach

Comment: You'll have be more specific as to what you want to do with the specific value. As it stands your question would suit a foreach, echoing out the values. Or setting them to vars

Comment: @JayBlanchard Not helpful since it doesn't use `->`...

Comment: Well that said, we could do some magic with `json_encode()` en `json_decode()` :P

Comment: Basically, i want to output the userid values in a string with comma separated from this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a multidimensional array, it is an array that contains objects, meaning you access the property inside of the object with an `->` , not with `[]`'s ---
 so to turn this into a list of comma-separated values, do this:

```
foreach($yourArray as $object){

   $finalString[] = $object->id; 

    }

echo implode(", ", $finalString);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we call your array $arr, then I would use array_map:

```
$userIds = array_map(function($obj) { return $obj->userid; }, $arr);
```

**If** you want to output csv, I would use fputcsv like this (for example):

```
$handle = fopen('php://output', 'rw');
fputcsv($handle, $userIds);
```

For more details on exporting to csv, see [Export to CSV via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php)