# Extracting Json Data from PHP log file and Adding in a new column

Tags: php, json, parsing, csv

I am newbie to php,
Here is my json file ,

```
{"hint_data":{"locations":["AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB","bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAdzdTAMFAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"route_name":["",""],"via_indices":[0,15],"via_points":[[25.299982,55.376873],[25.29874,55.369179]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":101,"total_distance":871},"route_geometry":"{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBjF","status_message":"Found route between points","status":0}
```

I need to extract the **total_time** only from the json and print the extracted total_time to a new column in a csv file,could someone please help me in that?

Comment: What does _new coumn in a csv file_ means??

Comment: column** Corrected

Comment: DO you want to write in the json again with a new field?

Comment: No ,i want to write a json f with a new table.

Comment: You need these: `$result['total_time'] = $result['route_summary']['total_time'];

$json = json_encode($result);`

Comment: The Question is not about to get the total_time only, Its about to put, _extracted total_time to a new column in a csv file_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these i think.

```
$json = '{"hint_data":{"locations":["AXQDAP____8AAAAABwAAABEAAAAYAAAAIwIAAERwAgAAAAAADgyCAef7TAMCAAEB","bOsDAP____8AAAAAAwAAAAcAAADFAQAAFAAAAEJwAgAAAAAANQeCAdzdTAMFAAEB"],"checksum":326195011},"route_name":["",""],"via_indices":[0,15],"via_points":[[25.299982,55.376873],[25.29874,55.369179]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"end_point":"","start_point":"","total_time":101,"total_distance":871},"route_geometry":"{_ego@m}|rhBpBaBvHuC`EuArEUtEtAlDvEnD`MlDvMli@hsEfFzn@QlTgNhwCs@fKwBjF","status_message":"Found route between points","status":0}';
$assoc = true;
$result = json_decode ($json, $assoc);
$result['total_time'] = $result['route_summary']['total_time'];

$json = json_encode($result);
```

Now its time to put these `$json` back to a file using `file_put_contents`.

```
file_put_contents('file.csv', $json );
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your json string into a json file, load it and you can use json_decode function to load it in PHP as an array.

```
$string = file_get_contents('file.json');
$json = json_decode($string, true);
$totalTime = $json['route_summary']['total_time']; // 101
```

How to export the results to CSV file afterwards you have examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php) on SO.

Comment: The Question is not about to get the total_time only, Its about to put, _extracted total_time to a new column in a csv file_.