# Writing into CSV/XLS file from input form

Tags: php, excel, email, csv

**WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:**

This is what i've created so far. It's writing in to .txt file and with a different format that i want to change.

Code:

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("emaillist.txt", "a+");
    $txt = $_POST['country'] . " -- " . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

    header("Location: http://www.myredirectlocation.com");
?>
```

So basically with this code i'm storing registered emails.
As of now my emails are stored like this in a .txt file:

```
USA -- email1@something.com

USA -- email2@something.com

Canada -- email3@something.com
```

**WHAT I NEED:**

I want to write into .csv or .xls file instead of .txt file.

And also i want it to make columns for each country and write in seperate rows. 
So it will look like this:

```
USA | Canada | Australia

email1@something.com | email2@something.com | email3@something.com
```

Comment: Sidenote: Are you sure you don't want to use a database for this? Files are a lot of work and storing emails in a text file, well.. let's only hope you've kept that under a heavy lock.

Comment: Yea, i just want a .csv file. I will need it to import in to another program anyway.

Comment: Well, if you're planning on using another program and may be db-related, you're working too hard. You can use a LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html, just saying. See also http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Comment: To help you with this: You can use a tab separator and just change the extension to `.csv`. See also https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/