# Html form answers to txt/word/excel file

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I am new on this domain and...i consider myself a rookie...and i want to do something for a website that is over my knowledges in this moment. 
I have a form in html and i want to generate the answers from that form to a txt/word/excel file. I have no idea how to do it. I saw that there are more than 1000 questions about it on this website but i couldn't find the answer that i need. Here's the form. Please help me. I must mention that i am just a 16 year old programmer with a bright future :)

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="content_item">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="chestionar_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-green.css" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="chestionar_files/formoid1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <form class="formoid-solid-green" style="background-color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#34495E;max-width:480px;min-width:150px" method="post">
            <div class="title"><h2>Chestionar</h2></div>
                <div class="element-checkbox"><label class="title">Sex</label>      <div class="column column1"><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Masculin"/ ><span>Masculin</span></label><label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Feminin"/ ><span>Feminin</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-textarea"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><textarea class="medium" name="textarea2" cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="Ocupatia"></textarea><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
                <div class="element-number"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="text" min="0" max="100" name="number1" placeholder="Varsta" value=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">De unde ati aflat de centrul nostru?</label>        <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="de la medicul de familie/specialist" /><span>de la medicul de familie/specialist</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio" value="de la un fost pacient(prieten/coleg/ruda)" /><span>de la un fost pacient(prieten/coleg/ruda)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de comunicarea directa si telefonica cu receptia?</label>       <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio2" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de informatiile obtinute la receptie?</label>       <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio3" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio3" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio3" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de respectarea datei si orei programarii?</label>       <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio4" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio4" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio4" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de profesionalismul asistentelor?</label>       <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio5" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio5" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio5" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de profesionalismul doctorilor?</label>     <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio6" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio6" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio6" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de timpul de asteptare al rezultatelor?</label>     <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio7" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio7" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio7" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de tarifele practicate per serviciu?</label>        <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio8" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio8" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio8" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Sunteti multumit(a) de informatiile obtinute de pe site-ul nostru?</label>      <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio9" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio9" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio9" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-separator"><hr><h3 class="section-break-title"></h3></div>
                <div class="element-radio"><label class="title">Care este impresia dumneavoastra generala despre centrul nostru?</label>        <div class="column column1"><label><input type="radio" name="radio10" value="Sunt multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio10" value="Sunt oarecum multumit(a)" /><span>Sunt oarecum multumit(a)</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="radio10" value="Sunt nemultumit(a)" /><span>Sunt nemultumit(a)</span></label></div><span class="clearfix"></span>
            </div>
                <div class="element-email"><label class="title"></label><div class="item-cont"><input class="large" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Email (optional)"/><span class="icon-place"></span></div></div>
                <div class="element-rating"><label class="title">Oferiti o nota centrului nostru</label><div class="rating"><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-5" name="rating" value="5" /><label for="rating-5" class="rating-star"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-4" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="rating-4" class="rating-star"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-3" name="rating" value="3" /><label for="rating-3" class="rating-star"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-2" name="rating" value="2" /><label for="rating-2" class="rating-star"></label><input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rating-1" name="rating" value="1" /><label for="rating-1" class="rating-star"></label></div></div>
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>

        <p class="frmd">
            <a href="http://formoid.com/v29.php">css form</a>
        </p>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="chestionar_files/formoid1/formoid-solid-green.js"></script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In php we usually .convert it to text or .csv, you will need to pass the values through and generate a .txt or .csv file using php. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php and http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fputcsv.asp

Answer (score 0):

To simply add the form contents to a text file is pretty straightforward - one method could be simply:

```
<?php
    /* create text file in same directory as script */
    $textfile = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'answers.txt';


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'] ){
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ){

            /* string with field name and submitted value */
            $qa = $field .':'.$answer.PHP_EOL;

            /* write the string to the textfile */
            file_put_contents( $textfile,$qa,FILE_APPEND | FILE_TEXT );
        }
    }
?>
```

When the form is submitted via `POST` each form element that is present in the POST array should have it's name and value added to the file. Writing to a `WORD` or `EXCEL` file is much more involved though there are helper libraries out on the interwebs to simplify the process. Hope the above helps a little.