# ConvertToCSV not exporting data more than 600

Tags: javascript, jquery, activex

Below is the code that I have used for exporting data to excel.

It works fine for data smaller 500 but it takes more time when data is bigger than 500 and hangs if I try to export 1000 data.

```
function ExportToCsv(fileName, tableName) {
get();
var data = GetCellValues(tableName);
var csv = ConvertToCsv(data);
var data;
var a;

var excel = new ActiveXObject ("Excel.Application"); 

excel.visible = true; 
var book = excel.Workbooks.Add (); 

var sheet = excel.Worksheets(1); 

data=csv.split(";");

for (var i=0,j=1; i<data.length-1;i++,j++)  
 {

     cellValue = data[i].split("^");


     for(var k=0,l=1;k<cellValue.length;k++,l++){


        if(l==1){
            a="A"+j;
        }else if(l==2){
            a="B"+j;
        }else if(l==3){
            a="C"+j;
        }else if(l==4){
            a="D"+j;
        }else if(l==5){
            a="E"+j;
        }else if(l==6){
            a="F"+j;
        }else if(l==7){
            a="G"+j;
        }                           

        sheet.Range(a) = cellValue[k];

    }
  }
  } 
    function GetCellValues(tableName) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableName);
  var tableArray = [];
  for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    tableArray[r] = [];
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      var text = table.rows[r].cells[c].textContent || table.rows[r].cells[c].innerText;
      tableArray[r][c] = text.trim();
    }
  }
  return tableArray;
}

function ConvertToCsv(objArray) {
  var array = typeof objArray != "object" ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
  var str = "";
  var line = "";
  var index;
  var line_next="";
  var value;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    line = "";
    var array1 = array[i];
    for (index in array1) {
      if (array1.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        value = array1[index] + "";
        line +=value.replace(/"/g, "\"\"") + "^";
      }

    }
    line = line.slice(0, -1);
    str += line +";"+ "\r\n";
    }

  return str;
}
function get(){

var table = document.getElementById('table_0');
var numRows = table.rows.length;
var category = "";
var rows = "<tr><td>Document</td><td>Number</td><td>Title</td><td>val</td><td>test To</td><td>Prefix</td><td>suffix</td></tr>";

for(var i=0;i<numRows;i++){
    var values = [];
    var cells1 = table.rows[i].cells;
    var checkBoxes = cells1[0].getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var counter=1; counter<checkBoxes.length; counter++){
        if(checkBoxes[counter].type =='checkbox' && checkBoxes[counter].checked == true){
            for(var ic=1,it=(cells1.length-1);ic<it;ic++){                                      
                if(cells1[0].innerHTML != null){
                    divs=cells1[ic].textContent;
                    values.push(divs);                      
                }               
            }
            rows = rows + "<tr><td>" + values[0].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[1].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[2].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[3].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[4].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[5].trim() + "</td><td>" + values[6].trim() + "</td></tr>";

        }           
    }
    $("#resultTable").html(rows);
    //$(rows).appendTo("#resultTable");
    $("#myDiv").hide();

}   
return true;
}
```

While trying to export data more than 600 IE hangs.

Is it because I am using activex?

Any other way I can modify the code for making it work with large data?

Comment: Please try this it may helps you:
https://gist.github.com/umairidrees/8952054#file-php-save-db-table-as-csv

or also check post there was similar post also at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Comment: can we do it using Activex?

Comment: But without using activex you can also create csv file it will work fine for ever..

Comment: without activex file is not getting downloaded it self, as i am using CMS tool where this feature is needed.