# spacing in CSV file while converting from array

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert sql query returned array in CSV file, but i am experiancing a wierd behavior of my code since 1st line of my csv file is coming out to be blanck and also line containing column headers is starting after two blocks. following is my code,

```
$csv = "name,job,salary,age \n";
$export = $this->model2->emp_data();
foreach ($export as $key => $value) { 
                $csv.=  $value['name'].','. $value['job'].','. $value['sal'].','.$value['age']."\n";
}
$filename ='excel.csv';
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$csv_handler = fopen('php://output', 'w');            
fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv);
fclose ($csv_handler);
```

$csv is giving me my header names, $export is the sql returned data
what am i oing wrong here ? thank you

sample input (query returned data) -

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => jeff1
            [job] => DBA
            [sal] => 6999
            [age] => 44
            [create] => test
            [update] => test

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
          [name] => jeff2
            [job] => DBA
            [sal] => 6999
            [age] => 44
            [create] => test
            [update] => test
        )
        ....so on
```

output - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u0Q8OgerLAGlq_r610W7KU0N0hnu0gZE

Comment: could you add a sample of input and of current output?

Comment: heyy jeff thank you for quick responce check the question i just did

Comment: Don't output your lines just by joining fields with commas -- it will break as soon as you get a field with a comma in it. Instead use [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) which will do all the proper escaping for you.

Comment: thank you @AlexHowansky i have been meaning to update the code to use fputcsv() .. will this solve the problem i am facing currently with the headers?

Comment: What is your PHP version and server details ? I also face the same issue. This started happening after upgrading to PHP 7

Comment: Try opening that CSV using some text editor (not Excel), and check if still there is a blank line at the beginning

Comment: Check: https://www.ozonesolutions.com/programming/2012/06/php-whitespace-issues-when-exporting-to-csv-files/

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya yes there is an empty space , but i dont understand where it is coming from?

Comment: i checked the function where i have wrote dowload method but there no empty lines there, is there any way of ignoring these white spaces

Comment: You might want to understand and try [this post's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432).