# Export php to csv without query OR

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

I have a php query working with no problems.  However, prior to exporting to a csv file, I need to use a regular expressions to customize the look of a few variables.  I have this working as well.

```
$form_field_number_UPD = preg_replace('(\W{3}.*)', '\n', $form_field_number);
```

My problem is that I need to export these customized variables, instead of the raw query results.

Is this possible?

Also,

I have been trying to use a regular expression in mysql 5.7 but have had no luck.
Is there a preg_replace equivalent in MySQL 5.7?
I haven't found one yet. There seems to be one in MySQL 7 but I cannot upgrade yet.

my php that I would like to find an mysql equivalent for:

```
$form_field_number_UPD = preg_replace('(\W{3}.*)', '\n', $form_field_number);
```

I tried below but it does not work.

```
REPLACE(fd.form_field_number, '(\W{3}.*)', '\n', 1, 5) AS New_Field
```

Thanks for any assistance, even if it is "look over here..."

Revised::

I have a checkbox group column where the results are:

```
result 1|~|result 1
result 2|~|result 2
result 3|~|result 3
```

The regex removes the |~| and everything to the right of it, so  the results are:

```
result 1
result 2
result 3
```

I can do this in php but need to get these results into a downloadable csv file.

Comment: I am really bad in regex (preg_replace). so what are you trying to replace?

Comment: I have a checkbox group column where the results are:
result 1|~|result 1
result 2|~|result 2
result 3|~|result 3

The regex removes the |~| and everything to the right of it, so  the results are:

result 1
result 2
result 3

I can do this in php but need to get these results into a downloadable csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest getting an array of the data you'd like to export into php using a MySQL `SELECT` query and using your php `preg_replace()` statement since you know that works. Exporting the replaced data to a csv file from the php array is pretty straightforward from there.

This link has answers with code samples of how this can be done: [Export to CSV via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php)

Answer (score 1):

If your column is always demarcated with the symbol `|~|`, you don't need a regular expression; look for occurrences of this exact sequence, and use `SUBSTR` to chop off the rest of your string:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(fd.form_field_number, 1, LOCATE('|~|', fd.form_field_number)-1) AS trimmed
FROM ...
```

Comment: This would be perfect but I need to add a replace.  My bad for not mentioning that the code I listed above is from a column in one row.  So technically it looks like: result 1|~|result 1\nresult 2|~|result 2\nresult 3|~|result 3.  so I would need to somehow combine the replace and substr.  Is this possible?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html. See if there's anything else you need there, while you are at it.

Comment: What kind of "data" is this, anyway? If this kind of material is in a single database cell, you are not really dealing with relational data and shouldn't try to do the whole job with SQL. Pull it into php, go to town with `regexp_replace()` and its friends, and write out the results with `fputcsv()`.