# fopen export csv only works if I "ECHO" the code

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, opencsv

it's the first time I try to export a csv with php and I'm having a problem, I'm trying to export all information from an array in CSV form, but when I'm doing the foreach to organize the information that goes to the array, after exporting the information only appears in the csv if I use the "ECHO" during the array, but that bothers me because it consumes more memory. How can I put the information in csv without using "Echo" during foreach ?

my code.

```
echo "name" . ',' . "lastname"  . ',' . "email" . ',' . "id" . ',' . "create"  . ',' . "group" . ',' . "region"  . ',' . "city"  . ',' . "postcode"  . ',' . "telephone" . "\n";
        $clients = array();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {



            $users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($item['entity_id']);


            $defaultBillingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($users->getData('default_billing'));


            echo $clients[] = $users->getData('firstname');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $users->getData('lastname');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $users->getData('email');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $users->getData('entity_id');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $users->getData('created_at');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $defaultBillingAddress->getData('region');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $defaultBillingAddress->getData('city');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $defaultBillingAddress->getData('postcode');
            echo $clients[] = ',' . $defaultBillingAddress->getData('telephone') . "\n";

            break;
        }


        $f = fopen('php://output', 'a');


        foreach ($clients as $clusters) {


            fputcsv($f, $clusters);
        }


        fclose($f);
```

Comment: You don't need `echo()` in there and frankly it looks wrong. What you probably want to do is "see" the results. For that use `var_dump()` or `print_r()` after you are finished your extractions. ... Also note that each time you do `[]` on the array, a new array index is created to store the value.

Comment: But why is the file blank because I don't use echo?

Comment: Good point. It's blank because of how you open the output file with this line `$f = fopen('php://output', 'a');`.  Where are you trying to export to ultimately? You can still use that line without all the echoes, just echo out the array after it separately.

Comment: I think this article you can check it
[Export to CSV via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php)

Comment: I think this article you can check it:
[Export to CSV via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export to CSV via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$f = fopen('php://output');
foreach ($collection as $item) {
   $row = [
       $users->getData('firstname'),
       ...
       $defaultBillingAddress->getData('telephone'),
   ];
   fputcsv($f, $row);
}
fclose($f);
```