# I want to remove the ',' dellimiter between " " in php

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-replace, preg-match

I want to remove the ',' dellimiter between " " only . Exmp : `"Alibris: Books, Music, & Movies"`

Output of 1st row should be

```
256,2653,"Alibris: Books  Music  & Movies",50263394,05/14/2013,07:44,50263394,114.85,1,5.74,05/14/2013,08:10
```

example of array here

```
Array
(
    [0] => 256,2653,"Alibris: Books, Music, & Movies",50263394,05/14/2013,07:44,50263394,114.85,1,5.74,05/14/2013,08:10,
    [1] => 256,2653,"Alibris: Books, Music, & Movies",50327805,05/21/2013,23:03,50327805,-6.99,1,-0.35,05/22/2013,07:10,
    [2] => 256,2653,"Alibris: Books, Music, & Movies",50327805,05/21/2013,23:03,50327805,6.99,1,0.35,05/22/2013,00:10,
    [3] => 527,36777,BuySKU,920130525042340263061,05/24/2013,20:25,1390043,"1,170.73",11,58.54,05/24/2013,20:55,
)
```

Comment: "what have you tried?"

Comment: You need to show your code and explain why it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: I want to split the row in array based on delimeter , but not into ""

Comment: I hope you're not doing this simply as a way to be lazy when parsing CSV files. If you are, think about using [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/str_getcsv) or [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
,(?!([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)+$|[^"]*$)
```

replace it with empty string

This would match , only if there are odd number of `"` ahead.So it would match `,` if its between `"`

[DEMO](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=,%28?!%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%22%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%29%2b%24%7C%5B%5E%22%5D%2a%24%29&input=dsfdsffdsfd,fds%20%22dfdsfdsf,%20%20dsf%22dsfdsfds%20,dfdsfdsffs%20%22fvdfsdf%20,dfsd%20dsf%20dsf%22)

So,it would be

```
$pattern = "/,(?!([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)+$|[^\"]*$)/"; 
$replace = ""; 
$line = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$line);
```

---

If you want to split it with `,` only its outside `"` use

```
 ,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*"[^"]*)+$|[^"]*$)
```

So it would be

```
preg_split('/,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)+$|[^\"]*$)/', $text);
```

Comment: If he uses that pattern with `preg_replace`, what should the replacement be to get rid of the commas?

Comment: @Barmar oops..edited the ans and a demo

Comment: I want to split the row in array based on delimeter , but not into ""

Comment: @intekhabkhan you want to split or replace..be clear with your question

Comment: @Barmar can you pass me code .. of this

Comment: @intekhabkhan check out the edit at end

Comment: @Anirudh I want to split the row in array. I m using  { ,}   delimeter but " " create problem beacuse of have {,} in ""

Comment: @intekhabkhan you can use `/,(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)+$|[^\"]*$)/` to split

Answer (score 2):

Here's the approach I suggest you take:

- For each line in the file

  - Read the line into an array using PHP's CSV functions (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
  - Modify the element of the array that you want to modify using, probably, str_replace.
  - Write out the array in CSV format (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

The key is that you need to get the string broken up into its component parts, rather than trying to modify certain commas but not others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_getcsv and a str_replace in a closure to accomplish this

```
$rec = str_getcsv($line);
$rec = array_map(
     function($x){
          return str_replace(",", "", $x); 
     },$rec);
```

Now you end up with an array that you can use in a  call to fputcsv

If you absolutely need the value as a string you can use a the str_putcsv implementation inplemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352591/convert-php-array-to-csv-string).

Note that this syntax (inline closures as well as the str_getcsv function) will only work in php 5.3+

Comment: Not working I m using this code :: 

foreach ($wrong_row as $khy => $vae) {
    $vae = str_replace(",","",$vae);
    }

Comment: @intekhabkhan That is because within the foreach $vae is passed by value instead of by reference so editing the value does nothing to the original array.