# File throws an error on download

Tags: php, csv, firefox, download

I'm generating a csv file for download using the following code.

```
/**@var array $results contains the results of an SQL query**/
$tmpFile = tmpfile(); //Create a temp file to write the csv to
fputcsv($tmpFile, array_keys($results[0])); //Write the column headers

foreach ($results as $result) { //write each row to the file
    fputcsv($tmpFile, $result);
}
rewind($tmpFile); //Rewind the stream
$csv = stream_get_contents($tmpFile); //Get the file as text
fclose($tmpFile); //Done with the temp file.

//Set the download headers
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="testDownload.csv"');
//Output the content
echo $csv;
exit(0);
```

The download appears to start normally, but after a second I get a message in firefox, "[The file] could not be saved, because the source file could not be read."  I've tested this with chrome/safari and have gotten similar results. I've also tested with some static content (not from the database) without success.

In the developer console, I can inspect the network request and see that it comes back with status 200 and if I inspect the response, I see the complete file.  I can even copy/paste it into a text file and open it in excel.

Additionally, if I comment out the `header()` lines, the file contents display in the browser without issue.

The content is only ~2500 rows, no special characters.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Can you please show us the first few lines of `$results`?

Comment: A question, why are you storing the data in a real temp file when all you seem to want is to output it? Here's an answer that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16353448/2453432

Comment: Possibly something to do with FF's compression settings?  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1026743#answer-644501

Comment: @magnus Erikson, interesting, as I understand it, php://temp and tempfile function the same way under the hood. Regardless, just tried that and the issue still happens.

Comment: @waterloomatt, I'll post some rows when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: ASFAIK, tempfile creates an actual file in the temp folder while php://temp stores the data in memory and never touches the file system

Comment: Happening in multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes, Firefox, Chrome, and safari. Haven't tested ie/edge