# Write Associative Array of Objects to CSV - php

Tags: php, csv, associative-array

I have associative array '$reportData' having objects of 'report_Modal'.

Attributes of 'report_Modal' are:

```
private $unique_product_name;
private $min_price_quote;
private $max_price_quote;
private $mean_price_quote;
private $price_variation;
private $savings_potential;
private $vendor_name_OLP;
```

All setters and getters exists for all private attributes.

I want to write all objects to CSV with header like:

```
Product Name,Min Price,Max Price,Mean Price,Price Variation,Savings Potential,
Vendor Name OLP
Memory Card,110,200,142.5,1.03,0.23,Kingston
USB,125,230,171.5,1.02,0.27,Sandisk
```

P.S: I am new to php

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php

Comment: No it isn't. Please suggest me solution instead of pointing as duplicate question. Thanks

Comment: You can loop through all objects by a foreach and use [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fputcsv.php) function to put data into csv

Comment: Is modifying the report_modal class a possibility?

Comment: In you report_modal  class have these methods for example or something like that: getMinPriceQuote(), getVendorNameOLP() ?

Comment: @rescobar yes, I have methods like getMinPriceQuote(), getVendorNameOLP() in report_modal class.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to access a list of private properties dynamically. Here's an example of a function that does that:

```
function toArray($report_modal, $properties) {
    return array_map(function($property) use ($report_modal) {
        return $report_modal->{'get_'.$property}();
        // modify according to how your methods are named
    }, $properties);
}
```

Then if you define the list of properties you want to get

```
$properties = [
    'unique_product_name',
    'min_price_quote',
    'max_price_quote',
    'mean_price_quote',
    'price_variation',
    'savings_potential',
    'vendor_name_OLP',
];
```

You can iterate your array of objects, convert them to arrays, and and output them to CSV.

```
foreach ($reports as $report) {
    fputcsv('outputfile.csv', toArray($report, $properties));
}
```

If you can modify the class, you could also implement a `toArray` method internally if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your array of objects into array of arrays, then use the function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13474770/5407848) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16353448/5407848)

```
<?php
$header = ['Product Name','Min Price','Max Price','Mean Price','Price Variation','Savings Potential','Vendor Name OLP'];
$finalArray = [$header];
foreach ($ascArray as $obj){
    $a = [];
    $a[] = $obj->get_unique_product_name();
    $a[] = $obj->get_min_price_quote();
    $a[] = $obj->get_max_price_quote();
    $a[] = $obj->get_mean_price_quote();
    $a[] = $obj->get_price_variation();
    $a[] = $obj->get_savings_potential();
    $a[] = $obj->get_vendor_name_OLP();

    $finalArray[] = $a;    
}
```