# PHP - Export to CSV an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, csv, export

I want to export an array of objects in CSV :

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  object(Produit)#228 (36) {
    ["id_produit":protected]=> string(4) "9999"
    ["reference":protected]=> string(9) "reference1"
}
  [1]=>
  object(Produit)#228 (36) {
    ["id_produit":protected]=> string(4) "8888"
    ["reference":protected]=> string(9) "reference2"
}
}
```

IN something like :

```
id_produit | reference | ...
9999 | reference1 | ...
8888 | reference2 | ...
```

The first row : **list of attribut / column**

The other row : **value of the attribut of the Object**

*True Example of array with object :* http://pastebin.com/8Eyf46pb

I tried this : [Convert array into csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv) but it doesn't work for me.

Is it possible to do this (and how ?) or I have to write each attribute in a loop ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be pretty easy if all your properties are public:

```
// Test class
class Produit
{
    public $id_produit;
    public $reference;

    // Test data
    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->id_produit = rand(1, 255);
        $this->reference = rand(1, 255);
    }
}

// Test data array
$array = array(new Produit(), new Produit());

// Notice, you can only use a single character as a delimiter
$delimiter = '|';

if (count($array) > 0) {
    // prepare the file
    $fp = fopen('test/file.csv', 'w');

    // Save header
    $header = array_keys((array)$array[0]);
    fputcsv($fp, $header, $delimiter);

    // Save data
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        fputcsv($fp, (array)$element, $delimiter);
    }
}
```

But as I can see, your properties are protected. Which means we can't access properties outside the object as well as loop through them or use **(array)** typecasting. So in this case you must make some changes ot the object:

```
// Test class
class Produit
{
    // ...

    public function getProperties()
    {
        return array('id_produit', 'reference');
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $result = array();

        foreach ($this->getProperties() as $property) {
            $result[$property] = $this->$property;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And then instead of typecasting you can use new method toArray like this:

```
// Save data
foreach ($array as $element) {
    fputcsv($fp, $element->toArray(), $delimiter);
}
```

Also thanks to new mehod getProperties we can change header getting:

```
// Save header
fputcsv($fp, $array[0]->getProperties(), $delimiter);
```

Comment: Thank you, I tested each of your example and I have the same result, is it normal ? (even if my propertie are protected)

Answer (score 1):

I've now tested the below code and it does seem to work. Reflection was the answer.

I tried to get it working on phpfiddle hence the php://temp but it didn't work unfortunately

```
<?php
class Produit
{
    public $id_produit;
    public $reference;

    // Test data
    public function  __construct()
    {
        $this->id_produit = rand(1, 255);
        $this->reference = rand(1, 255);
    }
}

$array = array(new Produit(), new Produit());


$delimiter='|';
$fp=fopen('php://temp', 'w'); //replace this bit with a file name
$header=false;
foreach($array as $Produit){
    $Reflection = new ReflectionClass($Produit);
    $properties = $Reflection->getProperties();
    $row=array();
    foreach($properties as $prop){
        $row[$prop->getName()] = $prop->getValue($Produit);
    }
    if(!$header){
        fputcsv($fp, array_keys($row), $delimiter);
        $header=true;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $row, $delimiter);
}

//now show what has been written, you will want to remove this section
fseek($fp, 0);
fpassthru($fp);
//ends

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the same result than the other post above.