# getting tables in database and store it in string

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to show list of tables to the database i am connected to but I cant place them in a string.
What i would like to happen is to get the list of tables from the database and store them in a string

```
$result = mysql_query("show tables"); // run the query and assign the result to $result

while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result
    if ($table) {
        $aw = array();
        $count= 0;                              
        $aw[$count] = $table[0];
        echo $string = array($aw[$count]);

        $count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `echo $string = array($aw[$count]);`.

In my opinion this should solve it too:

`echo $string = $aw[$count];`

As you commented you would like to have it in a CSV format, you can take a look at [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fputcsv.php) for example if you want to put it to a file directly. Otherwise here is a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv) which produce a CSV string.

Comment: thanks but i would also like to make the data in a csv format

Comment: i cant quite understand how the function which produce a CSV string  works could you please help me