# Write PHP array object to a csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I would like to ask that how can I write a php array std object to a csv file.

[Convert array to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv) Didn't solve my problem.

This is my Array

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lotNum] => 1
                [commissionRate] => 4.0%
                [detailUrl] => JEq7E6IEa
                [promotionVolume] => 0
                [packageType] => piece
                [price] => US $80.54
                [imageUrl] => BOX.jpg
                [subject] => Box
                [salePrice] => US $60.41
                [commission] => US $0.00
                [productId] => xxxx1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lotNum] => 1
                [commissionRate] => 4.0%
                [detailUrl] => JEq7E6IEa
                [promotionVolume] => 0
                [packageType] => piece
                [price] => US $80.54
                [imageUrl] => BOX.jpg
                [subject] => Box
                [salePrice] => US $60.41
                [commission] => US $0.00
                [productId] => xxxx1
            )
    )
```

How can I put data of each product in one row of csv file?
Thanks :)

Comment: use `PHP Excel`, see docs here https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 23):

Try following

```
<?php

//$list = ----your array

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp,get_object_vars($fields));
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! I can't give upvote as of now. You are awesome!

Answer (score 3):

You have objects within your array. Convert them to an array.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($myArray as $fields) {
    if( is_object($fields) )
        $fields = (array) $fields;
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```