# Shopware 6 TWIG / HTML Syntax question csv feed komma separated

Tags: csv, twig

i am building a twig template for shopware 6 productfeed for ebay.

If i separate the template with semicolon, all the rows and columns are clean and sorted. If i change the delimiter to comma it gets screwed :-/ Can someone check my code and help me with the right html syntax? I think something with the divs and ul's and li's have to be enclosed ?#
After rendering the template with products (some have commas in the description) the feed gets extra columns and so on i guess something with the desription part has to be faulty.

`

```
"{{ product.productNumber }}",{#- -#}
"de_DE",{#- -#}
{%- if context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id] is defined -%}
"{{ product.translated.name|length > 60 ? product.translated.name|slice(0, 85) : product.translated.name }} {{ context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id]|length > 60 ? context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id]|slice(0, 85) ~ '...' : context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id] }} {% if product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title is defined %}{{ product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title }}{% endif %}",{#- -#}
{% else %}
"{{ product.translated.name|length > 120 ? product.translated.name|slice(0, 85) ~ '...' : product.translated.name }} {% if product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title is defined %}{{ product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title }}{% endif %}",{#- -#}
{%- endif -%}
,{#- -#}
"{{ product.translated.description|replace({"\n":' ', "\r":' ','"':'""'})|raw }}",{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
"{{product.cover.media.url}}",{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(2,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(3,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(4,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(5,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(6,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(7,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(8,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(9,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(10,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(11,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(12,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(13,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(14,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(15,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(16,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(17,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(18,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(19,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(20,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(21,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(22,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(23,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(24,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
{%- if product.ean is defined and product.ean is not null -%}"{{ product.ean|u.truncate(16) }}"{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
"{{ product.productNumber }}",{#- -#}
{%- if product.manufacturer is not null -%}
"{{ product.manufacturer.name }}"
{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(1,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(1,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(2,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(2,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(3,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(3,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(4,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(4,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(5,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(5,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(6,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(6,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(7,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(7,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(8,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(8,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(9,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(9,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(10,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(10,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(11,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(11,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(12,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(12,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(13,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(13,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(14,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(14,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(15,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(15,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(16,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(16,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(17,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(17,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(18,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(18,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(19,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(19,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(20,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(20,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(21,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(21,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(22,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(22,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(23,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(23,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(24,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(24,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(25,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(25,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(26,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(26,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(27,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(27,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(28,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(28,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(29,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(29,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(30,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(30,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(31,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(31,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(32,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(32,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(33,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(33,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(34,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(34,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(35,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(35,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(36,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(36,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(37,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(37,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(38,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(38,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %},{#- -#}
"NEW",{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
"METRIC",{#- -#}
{%- if product.length is defined and product.length is not null -%}{{ product.length/10 }} cm{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.width is defined and product.width is not null -%}{{ product.width/10 }} cm{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.height is defined and product.height is not null -%}{{ product.height/10 }} cm{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
{%- if product.weight is defined and product.weight is not null -%}{{ product.weight|round }}{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
"0",{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
"{{ product.stock }}",{#- -#}
"EBAY_DE",{#- -#}
"{%- set break = false -%}{%- for pc in product.categories -%}{%- if break == false -%}{%- if pc.customFields -%}{%- if pc.customFields.diga_ebay_category_field is defined and pc.customFields.diga_ebay_category_field is not null -%}{{ pc.customFields.diga_ebay_category_field }}{% set break = true %}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}",{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
"shipping",{#- -#}
"payment",{#- -#}
"return",{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
,{#- -#}
{%- if context.extensions.digahoodextension.prices is defined and context.extensions.digahoodextension.prices is not null -%}{{ context.extensions.digahoodextension.prices[product.id]}}{%- endif -%},{#- -#}
```

`

Thanks in advance and best regards
mark

I just search and replaced the semicolons to commas this is the original code.

`

```
"{{ product.productNumber }}";{#- -#}
"de_DE";{#- -#}
{%- if context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id] is defined -%}
"{{ product.translated.name|length > 60 ? product.translated.name|slice(0, 85) : product.translated.name }} {{ context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id]|length > 60 ? context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id]|slice(0, 85) ~ '...' : context.extensions.digahoodextension.varianttitles[product.id] }} {% if product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title is defined %}{{ product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title }}{% endif %}";{#- -#}
{% else %}
"{{ product.translated.name|length > 120 ? product.translated.name|slice(0, 85) ~ '...' : product.translated.name }} {% if product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title is defined %}{{ product.customFields.custom_hoodtitle_title }}{% endif %}";{#- -#}
{%- endif -%}
;{#- -#}
"{{ product.translated.description|replace({"\n":' ', "\r":' ','"':'""'})|raw }}",{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
"{{product.cover.media.url}}";{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(2,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(3,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(4,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(5,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(6,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(7,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(8,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(9,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(10,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(11,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(12,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(13,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(14,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(15,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(16,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(17,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(18,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(19,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(20,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(21,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(22,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(23,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.media|length > 1 -%}
    {%- for mediaAssociation in product.media|slice(24,1) -%}
        {{ mediaAssociation.media.url }}
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
{%- if product.ean is defined and product.ean is not null -%}"{{ product.ean|u.truncate(16) }}"{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
"{{ product.productNumber }}";{#- -#}
{%- if product.manufacturer is not null -%}
"{{ product.manufacturer.name }}"
{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(1,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(1,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(2,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(2,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(3,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(3,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(4,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(4,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(5,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(5,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(6,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(6,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(7,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(7,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(8,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(8,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(9,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(9,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(10,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(10,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(11,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(11,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(12,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(12,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(13,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(13,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(14,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(14,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(15,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(15,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(16,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(16,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(17,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(17,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(18,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(18,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(19,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(19,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(20,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(20,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(21,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(21,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(22,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(22,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(23,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(23,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(24,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(24,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(25,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(25,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(26,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(26,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(27,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(27,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(28,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(28,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(29,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(29,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(30,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(30,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(31,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(31,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(32,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(32,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(33,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(33,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(34,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(34,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(35,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(35,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(36,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(36,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(37,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(37,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(38,1) %}{{ properties.group.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
{% for properties in product.properties|slice(38,1) %}{{ properties.name }}{% endfor %};{#- -#}
"NEW";{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
"METRIC";{#- -#}
{%- if product.length is defined and product.length is not null -%}{{ product.length/10 }} cm{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.width is defined and product.width is not null -%}{{ product.width/10 }} cm{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.height is defined and product.height is not null -%}{{ product.height/10 }} cm{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
{%- if product.weight is defined and product.weight is not null -%}{{ product.weight|round }}{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
"0";{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
"{{ product.stock }}";{#- -#}
"EBAY_DE";{#- -#}
"{%- set break = false -%}{%- for pc in product.categories -%}{%- if break == false -%}{%- if pc.customFields -%}{%- if pc.customFields.diga_ebay_category_field is defined and pc.customFields.diga_ebay_category_field is not null -%}{{ pc.customFields.diga_ebay_category_field }}{% set break = true %}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endif -%}{%- endfor -%}";{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
;{#- -#}
{%- if context.extensions.digahoodextension.prices is defined and context.extensions.digahoodextension.prices is not null -%}{{ context.extensions.digahoodextension.prices[product.id]}}{%- endif -%};{#- -#}
```

`

Comment: Wouldn't it be more easier/convenient to just create a PHP array and convert this to an CSV instead of trying to pull this off with twig? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv)

Comment: You mean i write a php file with the entities of product and place it on the server and run a cronjob on it ?

Comment: I don't know bout the cronjob, but you can create the CSV with the contents of the array. Twig tends to be all over the place with whitespacing (as you have noticed yourself as i can see you using `{%- ... -%}` to prevent whitespacing from occurring)