# php implode with quotes

Tags: php, arrays, string, csv, implode

Imploding  a simple array

would look like this

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

and that would return this

```
 lastname,email,phone
```

great, so i might do this instead

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode("','", $array);
$comma_separated = "'".$comma_separated."'";
```

and now i have what I want a nice pretty csv string

```
 'lastname','email','phone'
```

is there a better way to do this, it feels to me like there should be an optional parameter for implode am I missing something ?

Comment: I see a lot of comments about the provided answers being "slower". **It does not matter**. Choose the way which is clearer and more maintainable, worry about performance later, if at all.

Comment: The only drawback is it will produce one empty string if the array is empty. ie. equivalent to `$comma_separated = "''";`

Comment: Topically related: [Enclosing every field with double quotes in CSV file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31559174/2943403) and [Forcing fputcsv to Use Enclosure For *all* Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2489553/2943403) and [Alternative to fputcsv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16942531/2943403)

Comment: If this question is being asked as a means to prepare strings for a SQL query, then this is an XY Problem.  Passing an array of values into, say, an `IN` expression should be done via a prepared statement -- and here is that canonical: [How can I bind an array of strings with a mysqli prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17226762/2943403).  This question's [mcve] does not include the challenge of dealing with strings which already contain single quotes -- certainly something to be concerned with to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, the way that you're doing it is just fine. `implode()` only takes 1-2 parameters (if you just supply an array, it joins the pieces by an empty string).

Comment: its seems there is no speed difference in any of these solutions I'll just keep doing it they way I always have, thanks for everyones help

Answer (score 209):

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');


echo "'" . implode("','", $array) . "'";
```

Comment: Watch out for empty array while using this solution.

Comment: Thanks. I used this for `<ul> <li> {!! implode('</li><li>', session('messages')) !!} </li> </ul>`

Answer (score 51):

```
$ids = sprintf("'%s'", implode("','", $ids ) );
```

Answer (score 48):

You could use [**`array_map()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
function add_quotes($str) {
    return sprintf("'%s'", $str);
}

$csv =  implode(',', array_map('add_quotes', $array));
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/ggNW4RwO)

Also note that there is [**`fputcsv`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) if you want to write to a file.

Comment: @Felix Kling I suspect this would be slower as well ?

Comment: @mcgrailm, i ask again: slower than what?

Comment: @mcgrailm: Maybe, I suggest you make a benchmark and find out ;)

Comment: @Felix Kling  how do I do that ?

Comment: @mcgrailm put various echoes of `time()` and subtract them (at the start and end of your code)

Comment: This has the added benefit of allowing you to escape any single quotes which may appear in the array elements

Comment: str_pad is faster as i know. `$result = implode(', ', array_map(function ($e) {return str_pad($e, strlen($e) + 2, '\'', STR_PAD_BOTH);}, $str))` see http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php

Comment: one liner: `implode(',', array_map(fn($str) => "\"{$str}\"", $array));`

Comment: one liner version `$csv =  implode(',', array_map(function($str){ return sprintf("'%s'", $str); }, $array));`

Comment: This seems to work well but, as with my own attempt `"'" . str_replace(",", "','", rtrim(implode(',', $values), ',')) . "'"` , it also quotes integers which might not always be desirable unless you need string-integers for some reason. How can those be filtered out to not be quoted?

Comment: 2011 post, still valid. Now it's possible to use arrow functions: $csv=implode(',', array_map(fn($s)=>sprintf("'%s'", $s), $array));

Answer (score 24):

Don't know if it's quicker, but, you could save a line of code with your method:

**From**

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode("','", $array);
$comma_separated = "'".$comma_separated."'";
```

**To:**

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = "'".implode("','", $array)."'";
```

Comment: and i could further that but putting the definition of array in where the variable $array is in the last line but I the speed diff would be so finite

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use loops you can also do:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
foreach($array as &$value){
   $value = "'$value'";
}
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/O2kB4fRo

Comment: @mcgrailm, slower than what? Its basically the same thing as an `array_map` but without using `array_map`

Comment: slower than the way I currently create my csv string

Comment: @mcgrailm see @FelixKling's comment

Comment: +1 seem the only one correct answer - all other answers will produce empty string when trying to implode empty array. This one wont.

Comment: Thanks @DenisMatafonov :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
$id = array(2222,3333,4444,5555,6666);
$ids = "'".implode("','",$id)."'";
```

### Or

```
$ids = sprintf("'%s'", implode("','", $id ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can create such a function:

```
function implode_with_quotes(array $data)
{
    return sprintf("'%s'", implode("', '", $data));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is achieved using implode + preg_replace as follows:

```
$a = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', '"$1"', $a)); // "A","B","C"
$b = [];
implode(',', preg_replace('/^(.*)$/', '"$1"', $b)); // empty string
```

As you can see this also saves you from checking if the array is empty.

Answer (score 2):

try this code :

```
$data = 'ABC,DEF,GHI';

$str = "'".str_replace(',',"','",$data)."'";


echo $str;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the fopen/fputcsv sub-systems here's a snippet that builds an escaped CSV string from an associative array....

```
$output = '';
foreach ($list as $row) {
  $output .= '"' . implode('", "', array_values($row)) . '"' . "\r\n";
}
```

Or from a list of objects...

```
foreach ($list as $obj) {
  $output .= '"' . implode('", "', array_values((array) $obj)) . '"' . "\r\n";
}
```

Then you can output the string as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option, depending on what you need the array for:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
echo json_encode($array);
```

This will put '[' and ']' around the string, which you may or may not want.

Comment: Good solution. And Can have ltrim and rtim to remove square brackets [ and ].

Answer (score 1):

**Don't forget to escape your data!**
If you want to put data in a CSV file without [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function or put it in a SQL query use this code:

```
$comma_separated = "'" . implode("','", array_map('addslashes', $array)) . "'";
```

This code avoids SQL injection or data fragmentation when input array contains **single quotation** or **backslash** characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way also

```
<?php
$csv= '\'' . join(array('lastname', 'email', 'phone'),'\',').'\'';
echo $csv;
?>
```

Comment: join is just an alias of implode

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
echo "'" . implode("','", explode(',', $array)) . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an oldi but I just created this snippet

```
public static function quoted_implode($array = null, $sep = ','){
        $keys = null;
        if(null !== $array && is_array($array)){
            $keys = implode('"'. $sep .'"',$array);
            $keys =  '"'.$keys .'"';
        }
        return $keys;
}
```

I wrote it as a method but easy to transform to a plain function.

How to use (this is just a line of another method I working on)?

$js_output .= "\t".'input_ids:['.self::quoted_implode($options['input_ids']).'],'.PHP_EOL;

Results in:(js) input_ids:["test_number","test_input1","test_input2"],

Might help someone?

Answer (score 0):

Unconditionally wrapping the imploded string with quotes will result in an empty quoted string when the array is empty -- this doesn't feel ideal because it gives the same result as an array with a lone element containing empty string (an ambiguous result).

Instead, just use `preg_replace()` to target the start and end positions of each string and inject a quote on those positions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SGYlX))

```
$array = ['lastname', 'email', 'phone'];

echo implode(",", preg_replace('/^|$/', "'", $array));
```

This doesn't deal with the possibility of escaping single quotes that already exist in the values.  If you want to escape in-value single quotes with backslashes, you can make iterated calls of `addcslashes()` with single quotes nominated for escaping and manually concatenate the outer single quotes.  Don't worry about speed as a top priority -- making your application bug-free is the first concern. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JPSWH))

```
echo implode(",", array_map(fn($v) => "'" . addcslashes($v, "'") . "'", $array));
```