# What is wrong with this SQL IF Statement?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

so I am building a search script and meed to pass on two variables, but first I want to make sure that the SQL QUery is correct so I am hard-coding the variable for now. So my variable is

```
$comma_separated = "'Alberta','Ontario'";
```

This is getting passed through to the query, which looks like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 1=1";



if ($firstname)
$sql .= " AND firstname='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$firstname) . "'";

if ($surname)
$sql .= " AND surname='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$surname) . "'";

if ($province)
$sql .= " AND province='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$comma_separated) . "' WHERE province IN ($comma_separated)";

$sql .= " ORDER BY surname";
```

and then when the query runs, I get this message:

```
cannot run the query because: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE province IN ('Alberta','Ontario') ORDER BY surname LIMIT 0, 5' at line 1
```

But to me the query looks right, what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edited. Please see above.

Comment: You have used `WHERE` twice in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `WHERE` in there twice.  You also seem to be trying to filter on province values in two different ways.  Based on the assumption that `$province` will always be an array of values (even if only a single value is given), you can try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 1=1";

if (!empty($firstname)) {
    $sql .= " AND firstname='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$firstname) . "'";
}

if (!empty($surname)) {
    $sql .= " AND surname='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$surname) . "'";
}

if (!empty($province)) {
    array_walk($province, function($value, $key_not_used) use ($mysqli) {
        return mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $value);
    });
    $sql .= " AND province IN ('" . implode(',', $province) . "')";
}

$sql .= " ORDER BY surname";
```

Comment: Something is up with your syntax on the implode. When I echo it out, I get `" . implode(, $province) . "`.  I'll try to fix it while I wait for your comment, but you might beat me to the punch.

Comment: @JLA It looks fine to me. Have you done something different than what is shown with regards to string quoting? You might get that if you missed had a single quote somewhere earlier in that line.

Comment: I've double checked this and no results are being retrieved.

Comment: OK, so I got this figured out in a far less elegant way than you present @Mike Brant. But here it is:

So first I implode $province and then wrap it with single quotes as presented here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102398/php-implode-101-with-quotes).  SO my code looks like this: `$implosion = implode("','", $province);
$implosion = "'".$implosion."'";` And then I pass it through the query as you suggested earlier. `if ($province)
$sql .= " AND province IN ($implosion)";` And now everything works! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JLA Don't forget to escape that input before using it in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL contains two `WHERE`'s.

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE 1=1
                      AND firstname='fn'
                      AND surname='sn'
                      AND province='p'
                      WHERE province IN ($comma_separated)
                      ORDER BY surname
```

Change the last bit to:

```
$sql .= " AND province='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$comma_separated) . "' AND province IN ($comma_separated)";
```

Which becomes:

```
AND province='p'
AND province IN ('Alberta','Ontario')
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the last part to:

```
if ($province)
  $sql .= " AND province IN (" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$comma_separated) . ")";
```

Comment: This is wrong actually. The single quotes MUST be present around the string values. That string is not where the problem lies.

Comment: @MikeBrant yeah you're right. Dunno what I was thinking... Fixed it.