# Enclosing every field with double quotes in CSV file using PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I need to put all strings and number with double quotes in CSV file using PHP.

How can I create CSV file from PHP in all data within double quotes ?

I am using this code to generate CSV - I am using codeigniter framework

```
$array = array(
    array(
     (string)'XXX XX XX',
     (string)'3',
     (string)'68878353',
     (string)'',
     (string)'xxxx@xxxx.xxx.xx',
    ),
);

$this->load->helper('csv');
array_to_csv($array, 'blueform.csv');
```

**Output I am getting:**

```
"XXX XX XX",3,68878353,,xxxx@xxxx.xxx.xx
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"XXX XX XX","3","68878353","","xxxx@xxxx.xxx.xx"
```

**Code of array_to_csv**

```
if (!function_exists('array_to_csv')) {
    function array_to_csv($array, $download = "") {
        if ($download != "") {   
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $download . '"');
        }

        ob_start();
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
        $n = 0;
        foreach ($array as $line) {
            $n++;
            if (!fputcsv($f, $line)) {
                show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
            }
        }
        fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
        $str = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        if ($download == "") {
            return $str;
        } else {
            echo $str;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post the code related to this `---->` `array_to_csv` function too

Comment: standard practice with CSV files is to only wrap fields in quotes if the data contains a comma or a quote. That's what PHP's `fputcsv` function does, and it's what's expected by pretty much every CSV-reading software I've ever come across. Is there a specific reason you need something different? (I'm guessing you're importing the data into some crusty old software that enforces it's own strict requirements?)

Comment: @Simba I have specific reason for this ... I am generating this CSV file to upload to Singapore government website,  I can't able to upload file to site generated using PHP ... after I have compared  files - one file which I can upload and other file which I am generating using php .. I have find out that main difference is file  in  which I can upload have double quotes in all values

Comment: @Uchiha please check I have added array_to_csv code now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489553/forcing-fputcsv-to-use-enclosure-for-all-fields

Comment: Some fields may contain `\r` or `\n` - I needed all fields to be quote-enclosed to protect against inappropriately perceived line breaks (should only occur at end of line).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have got solution 
this function convert multi dimension array into CSV with double quote and

```
function arr_to_csv($arr)
  {
        $filePointer="export.csv";
        $delimiter=",";
        $enclosure='"';
        $dataArray =$arr;

        $string = "";

        // No leading delimiter
        $writeDelimiter = FALSE;
        //foreach($dataArray as $dataElement)
        foreach ($dataArray as $key1 => $value){
        foreach ($value as $key => $dataElement) 

         {
          // Replaces a double quote with two double quotes
          $dataElement=str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $dataElement);
          // Adds a delimiter before each field (except the first)
          // Encloses each field with $enclosure and adds it to the string
          if($writeDelimiter) $string .= $delimiter;
          // $new_string = $enclosure . $dataElement . $enclosure;
          $string .= $enclosure . $dataElement . $enclosure;
         // Delimiters are used every time except the first.
          $writeDelimiter = TRUE;
         } // end foreach($dataArray as $dataElement)

                $string .= "\n";

         }      
        // Append new line
        $string .= "\n";    
         //$string = "An infinite number of monkeys";
        print($newstring);
       // Write the string to the file
      // fwrite($filePointer,$string);
       header('Content-Type: application/csv');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filePointer.'";');
  }
```

Comment: I really dont see why you need to add the clutter you do to your strings and then remove it again later... Why not just add `PHP_EOL` after the end of the inner `foreach` instead of adding `|||`? And the way you have set up your code you should never see `|||,` so why do you try to replace it with newline? You also set $writeDelimiter to true for every pass of the function, why not just see if the string is blank?

Comment: @Canis I have made code change ... please check I have remove '|||' this

Answer (score 7):

When building a CSV in PHP, you should use the [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function available from PHP 5

From the documentation, there's the following parameters:

```
int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )
```

In that you have:

- the file resource you're writing to
- The data to put into the CSV
- The delimiter (the commas usually)
- The string enclosure (this is the bit you want for your quotes)
- Escape string (so if your data contains the enclosure character, you can escape it to avoid it looking like a new field)

As the defaults for that are `,` for the delimiter, and `"` for the enclosure, you'll not need to add more.  That will correctly cover the strings.  The numbers are a different matter.  There's a work around on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489553/forcing-fputcsv-to-use-enclosure-for-all-fields) which I found after typing most of this and then having issues with numbers still :

> Not happy with this solution but it is what I did and worked. The idea
>   is to set an empty char as enclosure character on fputcsv and add some
>   quotes on every element of your array.
>
> ```
> function encodeFunc($value) {
>     return "\"$value\"";
> }
>
> fputcsv($handler, array_map(encodeFunc, $array), ',', chr(0));
> ```

Comment: I have changed code      function test_fun(){ 
        $array = array(
    array(
    $this->encodeFunc('xx x x'),
    $this->encodeFunc('3'),
    $this->encodeFunc('68878353'),
    $this->encodeFunc(''),
    $this->encodeFunc('xx@xx.xx.xx'),  
    ),
   );
    //fputcsv($handler, array_map(encodeFunc, $array), ',', chr(0));
    //print_r($array);
     $this->load->helper('csv');
   array_to_csv($array, 'blueform.csv'); 
  }function encodeFunc($value) {
    return "\"$value\"";
}   output :  """xxxx xx xxx""","""3""","""68878353""","""""","""xx@xx.xx.x"""

Comment: Adding chr(0) for fputcsv enclosure will actually generate ASCII 0 Garbled when there is a value that needs to be enclosed.

Answer (score 2):

Concat the string with this `'"""';`

Example: `'"""' . {{String}}  . '"""';`

This should work, it worked for me. This is a way to enclose the string.

Answer (score 1):

I m using CSV helper here.

For Generating result from db query for ex.

```
$sTable = "MY_TABLE_NAME";

$query = $this->db->get($sTable);

$this->load->helper('csv');

query_to_csv($query, TRUE, 'records.csv');
```

In CSV Helper onLine number 65 There is the code for query_to_csv.

here is **csv_helper.php**.

I made a small edit there if you want everything with double inverted comma.

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CSV Helpers
 * Inspiration from PHP Cookbook by David Sklar and Adam Trachtenberg
 * 
 * @author      JÃ©rÃ´me Jaglale
 * @link        http://maestric.com/en/doc/php/codeigniter_csv
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Array to CSV
 *
 * download == "" -> return CSV string
 * download == "toto.csv" -> download file toto.csv
 */
if ( ! function_exists('array_to_csv'))
{
    function array_to_csv($array, $download = "")
    {
        if ($download != "")
        {   
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $download . '"');
        }       

        ob_start();
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
        $n = 0;     
        foreach ($array as $line)
        {
            $n++;
            if ( ! fputcsv($f, $line))
            {
                show_error("Can't write line $n: $line");
            }
        }
        fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
        $str = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        if ($download == "")
        {
            return $str;    
        }
        else
        {   
            echo $str;
        }       
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Query to CSV
 *
 * download == "" -> return CSV string
 * download == "toto.csv" -> download file toto.csv
 */
if ( ! function_exists('query_to_csv'))
{
    function query_to_csv($query, $headers = TRUE, $download = "")
    {
        if ( ! is_object($query) OR ! method_exists($query, 'list_fields'))
        {
            show_error('invalid query');
        }

        $array = array();

        if ($headers)
        {
            $line = array();
            foreach ($query->list_fields() as $name)
            {
                $line[] = '"'.$name.'"';
            }
            $array[] = $line;
        }

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $line = array();
            foreach ($row as $item)
            {
                $line[] = '"'.$item.'"';
            }
            $array[] = $line;
        }

        echo array_to_csv($array, $download);
    }
}

/* End of file csv_helper.php */
/* Location: ./system/helpers/csv_helper.php */
```

This will give Insert double inverted comma in column name as well as rows.
You can also remove "" this from column name.

[image]

Comment: I need double quotes when you open CSV file in text editor ...if you open this file in text editor it will show ""UI"" like this @bugfixer

Comment: @Anudeep - But where did u mention that you want to open this file in text editor

Comment: Read this [link](http://superuser.com/a/349900) to better understand behavior of CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [implode() function](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php) to make the code above even more simple:

```
$delimiter = ';';
$enclosure = '"';
$linefeed  = "\n";

$lines = array();
// traversing data, one row at a time
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $arr = array();
    // traversing row, col after col
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        // MySQL-style escaping double quotes
        $val = str_replace('"','""',$val);
        // wrapping each value in double quotes
        $arr[] = sprintf('%s%s%s',$enclosure,$val,$enclosure);
    }
    // generating formatted line and storing it
    $lines[] = implode($delimiter,$arr);
}
// join each lines to have the final output
$output = implode($linefeed,$lines);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just replace fputcsv with a home grown version. Now I'm taking your data-structure to always be a grid like traditional spreadshees and CSV-files.

```
function getQuotedString($arr){
    $buffer = "";
    foreach($arr as $line){
        $string = "";
        foreach($line as $data){
            // See if $string is no longer empty, meaning we need a comma to separate data
            if($string !== "") $string .= ',';
            $string .= '"' . $data . '"';
        }
        $buffer .= $string . PHP_EOL;
    }
    return $buffer;
}
```

Now use that in your code:

```
...
ob_start();
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or show_error("Can't open php://output");
$quotedData = getQuotedString($arr);

for ($written = 0; $written < strlen($data); $written += $fwrite) {
    $fwrite = fwrite($f, substr($data, $written));
    if ($fwrite === false) {
        return $written;
    }
}

fclose($f) or show_error("Can't close php://output");
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
...
```

You can then use $written to see how many bytes were written, or if you want to know how many lines there were you can just use sizeof($arr).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the implode function work beautifully for this?

```
$array = [ 
 (string)'XXX XX XX',
 (string)'3',
 (string)'68878353',
 (string)'',
 (string)'xxxx@xxxx.xxx.xx'
];
$csvData = '"' . implode('","', $array) . '"';
```

and then you can just write $csvData out to your file?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse there are other ways to handle it, but by using `fputcsv` and works for most scenarios.

```
if(!function_exists('array_to_csv')) {
    function array_to_csv($array, $download = "") {
        ob_start();
        $f = fopen('php://output', 'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
        $counter = count($array);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) { 
            if(!fputcsv($f, array_map(function($value) {  return '"'.$value.'"';  }, $array[$i]), ",", "\"")) {
                die("Can't write line $i: ".print_r($array[$i], true));
            }
        }
        fclose($f) or die("Can't close php://output");
        $str = str_replace('"""', '"', ob_get_contents());
        ob_end_clean();

        if(strlen($download) > 0) {
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$download.'"');
            echo $str;
        } else {
            return $str;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't take the effort of properly enclosing every filed with double quotes. There are **in-build php functions** available to do the job without error.

Not only double quotes, you will be in need for single quote (`'`), double quote (`"`), backslash (`\`) and NULL (the NULL byte).

Use [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write, and [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read, which will take care of all.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code little bit.

```
fputcsv($f, $line)
```

To

```
fputcsv($f,array_map('strval', $line), ',', '"')
```

Hope this will help you.

FYI: its in   array_to_csv