# Array string to csv in php

Tags: php, fputcsv

I have an array with string `array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => '0025')` i want to export to csv file but i got no 0 like this 25 when i export to csv file.

i try these code and i got result without 0

```
$data = array(
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "lastname" => "Johnson", "age" => '0025')
  );

  $colnames = array(
    'firstname' => "Fname",
    'lastname' => "Last name",
    'age' => "Age",
  );

  function map_colnames($input)
  {
    global $colnames;
    return isset($colnames[$input]) ? $colnames[$input] : $input;
  }

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    if($str == 't') $str = 'TRUE';
    if($str == 'f') $str = 'FALSE';
    if(preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
      $str = "$str";
    }
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  // filename for download
  $filename = "website_data_" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: text/csv");

  $out = fopen("php://output", 'rw');

  $flag = false;
  foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      $firstline = array_map(__NAMESPACE__ . '\map_colnames', array_keys($row));
      fputcsv($out, $firstline, ',', '"');
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
  }

  fclose($out);
  exit;
```

i got these result

```
Fname   Lastname   Age
MAry    Johnson    25
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: @B001ᛦ just an example hehe

Comment: What's the purpose of `$str = "$str"`? That doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Barmar yes it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Barmar but when i set $str = " '$str " i can get '0025  but i don want '

Comment: It removes the left padded 0s because fputscsv considers '0025' to be the number 25. See here for some discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489553/forcing-fputcsv-to-use-enclosure-for-all-fields

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. I get `Mary,Johnson,0025`

Comment: How are you viewing the results? Why do you have spaces between the fields instead of commas?

Comment: @Rajes You don't need that line at all. `fputcsv()` will add quotes around fields that need them.

Comment: Are you loading the file into a spreadsheet application? It's probably removing the zeroes because it sees it as a number.

Comment: @Barmar can you create an answer?

Comment: What would the answer say? As far as I can tell, there's no problem to fix.

Comment: @Barmar yes i open it with excel spreadsheet

Comment: Ask in [su] if there's a way to tell Excel not to do that.

Comment: @Barmar that's mean the code is produce 0025 to excel and excel split that 0?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559174/enclosing-every-field-with-double-quotes-in-csv-file-using-php) will help you.

Comment: Couldn't you see that by looking at the file in a text editor?

Comment: I just ran that code in http://phpfiddle.org/ and it works perfectly getting Fname,"Last name",Age
Mary,Johnson,0025

I think the problem is in the program you use to open the csv, open the file with text editor :)

Comment: @Barmar ok i got it thank you very much

Comment: @calm i got it thank you very much