# How to convert elements in an array to a formatted csv form? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below;

```
$carsarray = array("audi","toyota","ford");
```

I want to generate a string like;

```
'audi','toyota','ford'
```

Using implode function like;

```
$cars = implode(",",$carsarray);
```

I get output like

```
audi,toyota,ford
```

To get my desired output, I use;

```
$cars = "";
foreach($carsarray as $car){
    $cars .= "'".$car."',";
}
$cars = rtrim($cars,","); // this gives me 'audi','toyota','ford'
```

But, is there any other better / efficient method other than using these `foreach` or `while` or some other loops? I mean, something like an implode function?

Comment: I think easy way to convert is to use a library from github .. for example this one ->  https://github.com/jonseg/array-to-csv/

Comment: here is a similer one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102398/php-implode-101-with-quotes

Comment: Have a look at `fputcsv()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: you can add the single quotes to the `implode()` and concatenate a quoute to the start/end -> `$cars = "'".implode("','",$carsarray)."'";`

Comment: why -1? seems like down votes nowadays are not for question irrelevancy alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

`$cars = "'".implode("','",$carsarray)."'";`

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
$cars = "'" . implode("','", $carsarray) . "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$carsarray = array("audi","toyota","ford");
$your_result = "'";
$your_result .= implode("','",$carsarray);
$your_result .= "'";
```