# PHP add single quotes to comma separated list

Tags: php, arrays, string

When I implode my array I get a list that looks like this:

```
qwerty, QTPQ, FRQO
```

I need to add single quotes so it looks like:

```
'qwerty', 'QTPQ', 'FRQO'
```

Can this be done using PHP?

Comment: First try to implode your array into this format: `qwerty', 'QTPQ', 'FRQO` then you can add the quotes at the start and the end

Comment: You could do a search and replace...  where "," replace with "', '".

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6102398/3933332

Comment: can we remove the mysql tag ?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use `'` before and after implode()

```
$temp = array("abc","xyz");

$result = "'" . implode ( "', '", $temp ) . "'";

echo $result; // 'abc', 'xyz'
```

Answer (score 21):

Here is another way:

```
$arr = ['qwerty', 'QTPQ', 'FRQO'];

$str = implode(', ', array_map(function($val){return sprintf("'%s'", $val);}, $arr));

echo $str; //'qwerty', 'QTPQ', 'FRQO'
```

sprintf() is a clean way of wrapping the single quotes around each item in the array

array_map() executes this for each array item and returns the updated array

implode() then turns the updated array with into a string using a comma as glue

Answer (score 11):

It can also be as short as this:

```
sprintf("'%s'", implode("', '", $array))
```

Comment: Simple enough and worked great for me!!!

Answer (score 5):

You can set the glue to `', '` and then wrap the result in `'`

```
$res = "'" . implode ( "', '", $array ) . "'";
```

http://codepad.org/bkTHfkfx

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Rizier123 said, PHP's [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) method takes two arguments; the "glue" string and the "pieces" array.

so,

```
$str = implode(", ", $arr);
```

gives you the elements separated by a comma and a space, so

```
$str = implode("', '", $arr);
```

gives you the elements separated by `', '`.

From there all you need to do is concatenate your list with single quotes on either end.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($file as $newaarr) {
        array_push($ids, $newaarr['Identifiant']);

    }
   $ids =array_unique($ids);
    //$idAll=implode(',',$ids);

     $idAll = "'" . implode ( "', '", $ids ) . "'";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method called `'implode'` in the PHP.
That will help you to concatenate all the array values with th given delimiter.

```
$arr = ['qwe', 'asd', 'zxc'];
echo implode(',', array_map(function($i){return "'".$i."'";}, $arr));
```

You output will be something like below:

```
'qwe','asd','zxc'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function implode_string($data, $str_starter = "'", $str_ender = "'", $str_seperator = ",") {
    if (isset($data) && $data) {
        if (is_array($data)) {
            foreach ($data as $value) {
                $str[] = $str_starter . addslashes($value) . $str_ender . $str_seperator;
            }
            return (isset($str) && $str) ? implode($str_seperator, $str) :  null;
        }
        return $str_starter . $data . $str_ender;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this approach also

```
$sql = implode(", ", array_map(fn($arg) => "'$arg'", $arr));
```