# PHP add single quotes to comma separated list not working

Tags: php, csv

i follow

[PHP add single quotes to comma separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440610/php-add-single-quotes-to-comma-separated-list)

to add single quotes to comma separated list not working

```
 $result = $data;

 $str = "'" . implode ( "', '", $result ) . "'";


 //result --- insert into `pharmacy`.`tblsales` ( Invoice_No ) values (I17-
  07161)



  // tried following
 //$str = implode(";", $result); -- giving error :- Undefined 
  offset
 //$str = "'" . implode ( "', '", $result ) . "'";-- same error :- Undefined 
  offset
 //$str = implode("', '", $result); - same      

 $slice = explode(";", $str);
```

what can i modify more to get the result ?

Edit : var_dump($result) gives

```
array (size=35)
  0 => string 'I17-07161' (length=9)
  1 => string '06-11-2017' (length=10)
  2 => string 'NAUSARAN MEDICOSE' (length=17)
  3 => string 'SAHARANPUR' (length=10)
  4 => string 'TTINA0065' (length=9)
  5 => string 'ARBITEL CT 40' (length=13)
  6 => string '10'S' (length=4)
  7 => string '150' (length=3)
  8 => string '0' (length=1)
  9 => string '0' (length=1)
  10 => string 'ARIS0004' (length=8)
  11 => string '01-08-2017' (length=10)
  12 => string '31-07-2019' (length=10)
  13 => string 'ML-SIKKIM (ML24)' (length=16)
  14 => string '61.4' (length=4)
  15 => string '68.22' (length=5)
  16 => string '95.5' (length=4)
  17 => string '8,289.00' (length=8)
  18 => string '-10' (length=3)
  19 => string '-921' (length=4)
  20 => string '0' (length=1)
  21 => string '0' (length=1)
  22 => string '0' (length=1)
  23 => string '0' (length=1)
  24 => string '0' (length=1)
  25 => string '0' (length=1)
  26 => string '0' (length=1)
  27 => string '6' (length=1)
  28 => string '497.34' (length=6)
  29 => string '6' (length=1)
  30 => string '497.34' (length=6)
  31 => string '0' (length=1)
  32 => string '0' (length=1)
  33 => string '9,283.68' (length=8)
  34 => string 'CC' (length=2)
```

Comment: What does `$result` contain? What is the output of `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: `implode` is to assemble the elements of an array into a string using a "glue" (separator). Your errors seems to indicate `$result` is not an array(?)

Comment: i updated the result

Comment: If you're planning on using this to create SQL, for crying out loud *don't*. Look at using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = explode(',', $_data);
$str = implode("','", $result );
```

Comment: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Accidentally I typed $_data instead of $data.
Have you seen that?