# How can I convert a string of items broken by comma into double quote in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string for example:
apple,orange,melon,grape,peach

I want to take the items and display them like this:
"apple","orange","melon","grape","peach"

What is the most optimized way to reach this goal?

Comment: No regex needed. Split them by `,` and then use some string operation to put quotation marks on both ends.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6102398/3933332

Comment: @hanky-panky this is not at all the same as that. I saw this before making my question. Mine is actually not an array it is a string.

The answer you are referring to is only half of the way, you are assuming I know how to convert my string into an array.

Comment: Since I am not able to post answer posting it here. If your string is of the form `word,word,word` with no whitespaces anywhere you can search for word boundary `\b` and replace with `"`. [Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/69KfIA/1/) [Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/AZm8tl)

Comment: @HankyPanky: This question is not about converting string to array.

Comment: @HankyPanky yes if I knew the mix of the logics I could put 2 and 2 together. I mentioned I am looking for an optimized way of doing it. For someone who does not know either of the two, he/she would never know that they need to search first "how to split ..." and again search "implode ...".

There are a ton of posts (I assume) on Stackoverflow that can be answered by mixing a few questions together. That does not mean it is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = 'apple,orange,melon,grape,peach';
$string = explode(',', $string);
$string = '"' . implode('","', $string) . '"';
echo $string;
```

Compressed:

```
$string = 'apple,orange,melon,grape,peach';
echo '"' . implode('","', explode(',', $string)) . '"';
```