# PHP adding single quotes to comma separated string

Tags: php, string, delimiter, quote

I know I have done this before.  I am not sure why I am struggling to do something so simple.

All I am trying to do is add a single quote to a comma separated string.

The php process initially looks like this:

```
<?php
  $checknumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['checknumber']));

 $splitnumber = preg_replace('/\n$/','',preg_replace('/^\n/','',preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/',"\n",$checknumber )));

 $numbers = "'" . implode("', '", $splitnumber ) ."'";

 echo $checknumber;
 echo $splitnumber;
 echo $numbers;
?>
```

The results look like this:

```
// $checknumber
AMD111111,AMD222222,AMD333333

// $splitnumber
AMD111111,AMD222222,AMD333333

// $numbers
''
```

I need the results of $numbers to look like this:

```
'AMD111111','AMD222222','AMD333333'
```

The funny thing is I am using a piece of code I've used before that works.  So I am at a loss as to why the code is not working here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102398/php-implode-101-with-quotes

Comment: `$splitnumber` is a string, which is an invalid argument type for `implode()`'s second argument, so that function returns NULL. So you effectively have `$numbers = "'" . NULL . "'";`  which is `$numbers = "''";`  P.S. PHP will be raising an E_WARNING message complaining about the invalid argument type, be sure to turn up your error_reporting level and to turn on displaying errors (or log them).

Comment: @salathe - How can I fix this?

Comment: You're putting quotes on your imploded string, instead of putting quotes on the individual splitnumber.

Comment: It sounds like using the Implode is useless here.

Comment: @JohnBeasley it looks like you want `$splitnumber` to be an array like `array('AMD111111','AMD222222','AMD333333')`, so have a look at [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

Comment: Explode your database result. Do ya thing so the data is quoted and implode it.

Comment: I'm just thinking what'll happen if and when a user inputs a quote; that stands to possibly break your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implode() function requires an array as second argument.
It looks like your $splitnumber is just a simple string not an array of strings as it should probably be.
Try splitting your $splitnumber by commas using the explode() function and put the result of that in the implode function.

Should look like that (not tested):

```
$splitnumber = ...;
$splittedNumbers = explode(",", $splitnumber);
$numbers = "'" . implode("', '", $splittedNumbers) ."'";
```

There is probably a cleaner solution by just replacing all occurences of , with ','.

Comment: This is it!  This is what I was looking for.  Sheesh.  Such a simple task.  I don't even want to say how long I've been working on this today.  Thank you, sir.  This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

add like this "'".$rows['AccountNumber']."";

Answer (score -1):

Your implode isn't setup correctly.

```
$numbers = "'" . implode("','", $splitnumber) . "'";
```

Comment: I did try that, but I only got the same results.  I did not downvote you, my friend.

Comment: Your implode divider goes between the values. You would start without your first single quote and also will be without the last quote.