# how to enclose csv headers' row in double quotes using PHP?

Tags: php

if let's say I have

```
$headers = array(
"userid",
"fname",
"lname");
```

I want them to placed as header row (topmost part of the csv) separated by comma and enclosed each with double quotes.

I already tried

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w+'); 
fputcsv($fp,$headers,',','"');
fclose($fp);
```

they don't get enclosed with double quotes..how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing fputcsv to Use Enclosure For \*all\* Fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489553/forcing-fputcsv-to-use-enclosure-for-all-fields)

Comment: the url you pasted did not provide some help at all

Comment: because it's not possible. Have you tried manually adding the quotes, like so: `array('"userid'" ...)`

Comment: @ChenAsraf, if I do that, the output will be like e.g """userid"""

Comment: Also try to set the $enclosure parameter to an empty string to not include it in the "needs to be enclosed" characters

Comment: cool, that helped @ChenAsraf can you put your comment on a separate answer so that I can choose it as best answer? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to force it like so:

```
$headers = array(
    '"userid"',
    '"fname"',
    '"lname"'
);
```

By wrapping the values in actual quotes, and then just use a blank enclosure string:

```
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w+'); 
fputcsv($fp,$headers,',','');
fclose($fp);
```

To force it to exclude your quotes in the "needs to be enclosed" characters (PHP checks if the enclosure character is already inside the string, and escapes+encloses if necessary).

However, in new versions of PHP, you will get this error:

```
fputcsv(): enclosure must be a character
```

In which case, I would just recommend doing it yourself, like so:

```
function put_csv_headers($handle, $headers, $separator, $enclosure) {
    // [add some error checks here, of course]
    array_walk($headers, function(&$item, $i, $enc) {
        $item = $enc . $item . $enc; // wrap the header with the enclosure
    }, $enclosure);
    fputs($handle, implode($separator, $headers));
}
```

And:

```
$headers = array('userid', 'fname', 'lname');
$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w+'); 
put_csv_headers($fp, $headers, ',', '"');
fclose($fp);
```